# How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?

Tags: kernel

I was trying to delete old kernels, but I must have deleted all of the kernels on my Ubuntu 11.04 laptop. Is there any way to fix this via USB boot or mounting hard drive on another system?

Comment: Related: [How to restore deleted files in /boot? (vmlinuz missing, system does not boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696409/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-boot-vmlinuz-missing-system-does-not-boot)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Boot into a live CD (or live USB), mount some systems, chroot into it and install the kernel. After a successful installation of the kernel, unmount the filesystems.

1. Open Terminal
2. Mount the Ubuntu partition: `sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`
3. Mount some special partitions:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```
4. (optional) When you are connected to a network, use the DNS servers from your Live environment (otherwise host names can possibly not be resolved):

   ```
   cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
   ```
5. Chroot into the `/mnt`: `sudo chroot /mnt`
6. Install the Linux kernel: `apt-get install linux-image-generic` (no sudo required as you are root after a chroot)
7. After a successful installation of the kernel, get out the chroot and unmount some filesystems:

   ```
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt/sys
   sudo umount /mnt/proc
   sudo umount /mnt/dev
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```
8. Reboot and remove CD or USB: `sudo reboot`

Comment: It's what I would have suggested. I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming. I've added the finalizing steps as well, unmounting `/mnt`. Ubuntu usually takes care of unmounting/syncing the filesystems, but this looks cleaner to me.

Comment: If we have RAID10 how we can recover the same ?

Comment: @MaheshKatta You'll need to mount the RAID first. So instead of step two (where you mount a single drive) you'll be mapping a `/dev/mdxxx` drive - assuming it's mdadm.

Comment: When I `chroot` into `mnt` I'm no longer able to access the Internet. how can I fix this?

Comment: @James Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` (remove it if it is a symlink) and put something like `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in it (Google public DNS server). Replace it if necessary.

Comment: I have the same issue as james. Cant get to the internet through apt-get. Brpwser works fine though. Even with 8.8.8.8

Comment: Nvm. It looks like I had to edit the file in chroot itself. Maybe you should add to the answer `cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf` before going into chroot. That worked for me anyway

Comment: I couldn't execute `apt-get install linux-image-generic` until I copied the `resolv.config` file as pointed out by the author. Caution: I had to execute the command to copy the `resolv.config` file **before** `chroot` into `/mnt`. Otherwise I get an exception 'no such file or folder'

Comment: I got an error `cp: not writing through dangling symlink` when copying over the resolv.conf.  I fixed it with `sudo cp --remove-destination <path to resolv.conf> /mnt/etc/.`

Comment: Also, If you changed the actual file and not the symlink, once rebooted you can `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` then reboot to restore the resolv.conf file.

Comment: `sudo chroot /mnt` doesn't work. `ubuntu@ubuntu:/bin$ sudo chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`I tried using another OS installed in another partition and also using live USB. `/etc/resolve.conf` looks like- `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1`

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY ! You saved my life. THanks !!!!!!

Answer (score 66):

*This **expanded procedure** accounts for most of the complications that could occur, including problems connecting to the Internet in the `chroot`, not knowing which kernel package to install (before Ubuntu 12.10, it will not **always** be `linux-image-generic`), not knowing at the outset which partition or even which physical drive contains the `/` filesystem, and having a separate `/boot` partition.*

*I have not written this with reference to any of the other procedures here, though you will notice some similarities. I did base it, loosely, on [the procedure here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) (though those instructions are for something quite different, I have adapted them extensively, and only some commands, not prose, are copied).*

You removed all the kernel packages, and Ubuntu cannot boot without a kernel installed. So the solution is to boot from a live CD/DVD/USB, [`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) into the installed system, and install a kernel in it.

1. Boot from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive.
2. Select **Try Ubuntu** (not **Install Ubuntu**).
3. When the desktop comes up, make sure you are connected to the Internet. If you are not, connect to the Internet. One way to see if you are connected to the Internet is to open a web browser. You can even follow the rest of the instructions by bringing this Ask Ubuntu answer up in your web browser, in the live CD/DVD/USB system. I strongly recommend doing that.
4. Open a Terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
5. In the Terminal window, run this command to list your partitions:

   ```
    sudo parted -l
   ```

   You'll see something like this (but it won't be *exactly* like this):

   ```
   Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
   Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition Table: msdos

   Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
    1      1049kB  20.4GB  20.4GB  primary   ext4            boot
    2      20.4GB  21.5GB  1072MB  extended
    5      20.4GB  21.5GB  1072MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


   Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
   has been opened read-only.
   Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
   ```
6. Examine the output you got, to determine the device name of the partition that contains the [`/` filesystem](http://www.linfo.org/root_filesystem.html) of the Ubuntu system that is installed on the hard drive (that you are repairing).

   - If you only have one `ext4` partition, that's the one.
   - If you have more than one `ext4` partition, it's probably the first one. However, if the first one is very small--less than a gigabyte--then that might be a separate `/boot` partition (remember that one too).

     *Please note that whether or not `boot` is listed under `Flags` has very little to do with whether or not a partition is a separate `/boot` partition. My system, whose information is listed above, does **not** have a separate `/boot` partition.*
   - The device name for the partition starts with the device name for the physical drive, stated immediately after `Disk` in the second line. Then just add the partition number to the end of that. So, the device name for the partition that contains **my** `/` filesystem is `/dev/sda1`. Here are the two lines where I found that information:

     ```
     Disk /dev/sda: 21.5GB
     ```

     ```
      1      1049kB  20.4GB  20.4GB  primary   ext4            boot
     ```
   - If you have more than one physical drive, you'll get more than one listing like what is shown above. But unless you have another Unix-like system installed, you probably will only have one drive that contains `ext4` partitions, at least without having created them intentionally on another drive. If you do have multiple drives with `ext4` partitions, then the `ext4` partition that contains your `/` filesystem is probably on a drive that *also* contains a `linux-swap` partition.
   - It's *possible* that your Ubuntu system's `/` filesystem is on a partition of type other than `ext4`. When this happens, it's almost always `ext3`, and almost always on a quite old system. It's very uncommon for this to be the case, unless you intentionally set things up this way yourself.

   Remember the device name of the partition that contained your `/` filesystem (or write it down). *If it's different from **`/dev/sda1`**, then you'll replace **`/dev/sda1`** with it in the steps below.*

   (If it looked like you have a separate `/boot` partition, remember the device name for that, too.)
7. Mount the `/` filesystem to `/mnt`, and mount its `/dev` filesystem:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   ```
8. Check if the broken Ubuntu system you're repairing has a separate `/boot` partition which must be mounted separately. (If you are *sure* it does not, you can skip this.)

   To check, run:

   ```
   ls /mnt/boot
   ```

   If there is output (like `grub  memtest86+.bin  memtest86+_multiboot.bin`, but not necessarily exactly that), then the broken system's `/boot` is on the same partition as its `/` and you don't have to mount anything to access it.

   But if there is no output, then you will have to mount the `/boot` filesystem:

   ```
   sudo mount BOOT-PARTITION /mnt/boot
   ```

   Replace **`BOOT-PARTITION`** with the device name of the `/boot` partition (see step 6 above).
9. [`chroot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chroot.8.html) into the broken system, mount the remaining important virtual filesystems, and set some important environment variables:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   mount -t proc none /proc
   mount -t sysfs none /sys
   mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
   export HOME=/root
   export LC_ALL=C
   ```
10. Determine if Internet access works from within the `chroot` by [`ping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/ping.8.html)ing some reliable host that is known to respond normally to pings:

    ```
    ping -c 5 www.google.com
    ```

    You should see something like this:

    ```
    PING www.l.google.com (74.125.131.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from vc-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.131.147): icmp_req=1 ttl=44 time=61.3 ms
    64 bytes from vc-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.131.147): icmp_req=2 ttl=44 time=62.3 ms
    64 bytes from vc-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.131.147): icmp_req=3 ttl=44 time=61.8 ms
    64 bytes from vc-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.131.147): icmp_req=4 ttl=44 time=63.8 ms
    64 bytes from vc-in-f147.1e100.net (74.125.131.147): icmp_req=5 ttl=44 time=66.6 ms

    --- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
    5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 61.367/63.212/66.608/1.897 ms
    ```

    - If it looks mostly like that, and the number before `% packet loss` is less than 100, then the Internet connection in the `chroot` is working:

      ```
      5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
      ```

      It's working, so you can **skip step 11**.
    - If it looks mostly like that, and the number before `% packet loss` is 100, the connection needs troubleshooting. Make sure the connection on the live CD system (for example, through a web browser, or by running the same command in a separate, non-`chroot`ed Terminal tab/window) works. Make sure you're typing the command correctly. Use `www.google.com` if you haven't been.
    - If the output doesn't look like the above at all, but instead says `ping: unknown host www.google.com`, then networking isn't working yet in the `chroot`.
11. Set up networking in the `chroot`. **Skip this step unless you got an `unknown host` error in step 10 above.**

    To set up networking, back up the broken system's `hosts` file, and copy over the live CD system's `hosts` and `resolv.conf` files. (You don't have to back up the broken system's version of `resolv.conf`, as that file is automatically regenerated on-the-fly.)

    Open a **new Terminal tab** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or, if you prefer, a **new Terminal window** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Run these commands in it:

    ```
    sudo cp /mnt/etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts.old
    sudo cp /etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts
    sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
    exit
    ```

    (The `exit` command at the end closes the new tab/window.)

    Repeat step 10 above to make sure Internet access works now from within the `chroot`. It should.
12. Figure out which kernel package should be installed. Usually, this will be `linux-image-generic`. But not always.

    If you're not sure which to install, it will depend partly on which Ubuntu release you have installed, and partly on other information. If you are not sure which Ubuntu release you have installed, find out by running this command (in the `chroot`, *not* in a separate Terminal window/tab):

    ```
    lsb_release -r
    ```

    - On Ubuntu 12.10 (the next Ubuntu release, currently in development), it *always* will be `linux-image-generic`. (See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal.2C_unreleased.29_and_onwards), [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/TechnicalOverview/Alpha1#Linux_kernel_3.4), and [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-May/035176.html).)
    - On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, likely possibilities are `linux-image-generic` and `linux-image-generic-pae`. (Unlike previous versions, 12.04 no longer has separate server and desktop kernels.)

      - If the installed Ubuntu system (that you are fixing) is the 64-bit version, use `linux-image-generic`. (`linux-image-generic-pae` only applies to 32-bit systems.)

        It's possible to have a 32-bit Ubuntu system installed on a 32-bit or 64-bit computer. Furthermore, you might be using a 32-bit or 64-bit live CD to fix a 32-bit installed system. So if you don't know whether the *installed Ubuntu system* is 32-bit or 64-bit, check by running this command (in the `chroot`, *not* in a separate Terminal window/tab):

        ```
        dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS
        ```

        The output will be either `32` or `64`.

        <sup>(Please note that `uname -m` is **not** a correct way to find this information, because even when run in the `chroot`, that will tell you the architecture of the *running kernel*, which is the live CD system's kernel and not the installed (broken) system's kernel.)</sup>
      - If the installed Ubuntu system (that you are fixing) is the 32-bit version, the best kernel to use will depend on how much RAM you have. I recommend:

        - `linux-image-generic` if you have less than 3 GB of RAM
        - `linux-image-generic-pae` if you have 3 GB of RAM or more.

        <sup>(This is how Ubuntu's installer chooses which one to set up, ever since the installer gained the ability to install PAE kernels. See [the resolution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell/+bug/413135/comments/2) to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell/+bug/413135). If you want to learn what PAE is, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension). If you want to learn about PAE in Ubuntu, see [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE).)</sup>

        If you don't know how much RAM you have, run this command to find out:

        ```
        grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
        ```

        That is listed in [kilobytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte). To convert to [gigabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte), divide by 1,048,576 (1024<sup>2</sup>).

        - 3 gigs = 3,145,728 kB
    - On Ubuntu releases *before* 12.04, likely possibilities are `linux-image-generic`, `linux-image-generic-pae`, and `linux-image-server`.

      - If you're running an Ubuntu Server system, use `linux-image-server`.
      - Otherwise, follow the advice above for 12.04 systems.
13. This is the moment you've been waiting for! Install a kernel in the broken system.

    (Like before, except where explicitly indicated otherwise, these commands are run in the `chroot`, not in a separate Terminal window/tab.)

    ```
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
    ```

    Replace **`linux-image-generic`** with whatever other kernel package you decided to install in step 12 above, if different.
14. If you had to perform step 11 to set up networking in the `chroot`, restore the old `hosts` file. **If you skipped step 11, skip this step too.**

    To restore it, run this command:

    ```
    cp /etc/hosts.old /etc/hosts
    ```
15. Unmount filesystems, `exit`ing out of the `chroot`:

    ```
    umount /proc || umount -lf /proc
    umount /sys /dev/pts
    exit
    sudo umount /mnt/dev /mnt
    ```
16. Shut down the live CD/DVD/USB system, removing the live CD/DVD or USB flash drive. Boot into the system installed on the hard drive, that you just repaired. You've installed a kernel package in it (and as part of the installation, the kernel it provides will be added back to the GRUB2 boot menu). If everything worked correctly, your system should boot without problems. (I think it's possible that it will take a little longer to boot than usual, this time.)

DISCLAIMER: I did not test the above procedure on *every possible* Ubuntu system, so it is possible there is a mistake in it that I have not identified.

In the future, I recommend always trying to keep *two* kernels installed. It's good to have two in case one of them stops working for any reason (you can select the other in the GRUB2 boot menu). Plus, if you intend to keep *two* kernels and you accidentally uninstall one more than you meant to and reboot, you still have one left to boot from.

Comment: This may be the best written explanation of how to do something complex in Linux I've ever read. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much Eliah - after stupidly removing all my linux images, you saved my bacon. The only hiccup I had was at the step: sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf I got a "cp: not writing through dangling symlink `/mnt/etc/resolv.conf'" error. I found this [thread](http://community.plus.net/forum/?topic=113899.msg981747) and followed the instructions by one poster to: "rm /mnt/etc/resolv.conf" before "cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf" to solve the dangling symlink problem.

Comment: @xcal400 `/etc/resolv.conf` is nowadays managed by `resolvconf`, it'll automatically be generated when using NetworkManager and can safely be removed using `rm /etc/resolv.conf` as you found out.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice. One crap. Can i skip downloading kernel image from internet instead use offline available kernel package, or the one running as live cd ?

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: These steps did not generate the grub menu entry for me for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. I am currently using grub command line to boot. Please refer this new question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753352/how-to-regenerate-grub-menu-entries-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-after-deleting-all-ke

Comment: Well... Reading this I realized that i should never again play with my kernels and i should just download a new iso and press the 2 buttons to reinstall linux while shouting "good job idiot" to myself... All in all, today was a good day...

Comment: This has to be one of the best and most thorough answers I've ever read, and it really saved my hide after screwing up big time with a rather important virtual machine.

If I may add, this also works with systems installed on LVM volumes, just be sure to mount the right LVM volume in _/mnt_.

Comment: Needs additional steps for also fixing grub.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Have you had a situation where all kernels were uninstalled, you followed this procedure, it appeared to work but the system was not bootable, and then when you reinstalled GRUB it started working again? And if so, is it possible that GRUB was also *separately* broken? I don't think removing all kernels should break GRUB. GRUB gets configured to boot into the new kernel when the kernel is installed, I've never reinstalled GRUB while following this procedure but it has still always worked for me, and this is the first feedback I've got that it may be needed. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Grub was updated with no kernels present. It only setup memtest boot options. After the repair, 4.4.0-53 is installed, but grub won't see it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've tried to reproduce this on 16.04, but GRUB saw my kernels even when I ran `update-grub` after removing them (but before rebooting) and didn't run `update-grub` again from the chroot. Installing any kernel package should update GRUB, or any time your kernel metapackage pulled in a new kernel package, you'd have to do it manually. Have you ever edited any GRUB config files? Did you install `linux-image-generic` in the chroot, or a different package? And when was this? 4.4.0-53 is no longer either of the two most recent 16.04 kernels. (Btw, I'm in [chat], if that's convenient.)

Comment: I'd already gone to bed, or the chat help would have been great :) I did get this fixed. I had to use a --reinstall switch when installing the kernel, and then grub would detect it. Somehow they were only partially installed. Even then, though, it wouldn't boot. This system uses an LVM root partition, and grub wasn't putting that into menu.lst correctly. Once I manually edited that file, things were good.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Are these instructions still applicable to Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS? By the way, as an example of excellent technical writing, your instructions are excellent. (I am an ex techo writer.)

Comment: I had trouble with `grub` finding the new image, maybe I needed to mount efi or something in the `chroot` environment.  But I was able to boot into an older kernel via recovery mode, and then update grub manually.  After that a reboot worked fine. (Ubuntu 19.10)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add my experience I went through today in upgrading to Willy. I cleaned up a little bit and I found myself with only memtest. google led me to understand that I had removed the kernels. One constraint I had is slow network and so downloading full ISO was not option. So I used [Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (40MB only) and booted on it. After detecting hardware option (which helped me connect to wireless) I went into shell  option. I followed @Lekensteyn instructions and I succeeded. few things though: you have to copy `resolv.conf` before going chroot or else your DNS will be screwed and since the logged in user there is root no need for sudo anywhere.

I know its old but I thought adding this answer will add value to those wo would encounter the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed my kernel I found this solution on Ubuntu Forums. I followed every step and system was recovered. Hope it would help you.

A chroot might work, chroot means that when you start a system you change the root file system. For example you started from a live CD but you change the root "/" to where your ubuntu is installed.

Lets say your ubuntu is installed on /dev/sda2 then you can try the following commands:

Code:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
sudo cp /etc/hosts /mnt/etc/
sudo mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/dev
sudo chroot /mnt
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C
dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

now you're root "/" is on /dev/sda2, try installing the kernel

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-2.6.32-26-generic
update-initramfs -cv -k all
update-grub
```

I had to do a little guesswork here since I never had to do this before but this should be about it. Don't know if you get some fstab error warning (like can't find root).

Now you need to clean up some stuff and unmount the mounted partitions:
Code:

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
rm /etc/hosts
rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
rm /sbin/initctl
dpkg-divert --rename --remove /sbin/initctl
umount /proc # if this doesn't work try umount -lf /proc
umount /sys
umount /dev/pts
exit
sudo umount /mnt
```

And you can reboot to see if it worked.

URL for the thread: http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688928

Comment: Why would you replace `/etc/hosts` and remove `/sbin/initctl`? It's there for a reason.

Comment: This seems ultimately based on [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization); some steps are not necessary for repairing an already installed system. In particular, don't need to do anything with `/sbin/initctl` or `dbus-uuidgen` or `dpkg-divert`. You *might* need to replace `/etc/hosts` to connect to the Internet, but not usually, and if you do, you should put the original back. On an installed system (rather than a live CD that boots then unpacks a squashfs filesystem), you don't have to run `update-initramfs` or even `update-grub` after installing the kernel.

Comment: Also, since this procedure doesn't install any kernel metapackage, the kernel may not be properly updated later, unless a metapackage is installed. Furthermore, `linux-image-2.6.32-26-generic` will not be the right kernel for most people to install.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed old kernels from Trusty14.04 yesterday (FTR: I did *not* remove the two most recent ones!) my system wouldn't boot anymore. GRUB showed

```
Error: File not found
Error: You need to load the kernel first
```

No idea why.

I then followed [Eliah Kagan's excellent instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/166010/91549) to install `linux-image-generic` from a live CD. It did install 150 MB of new kernel, but sadly that didn't solve the problem.

Fortunately, I found [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). The `Boot-Repair` tool got it right, my system is running again.