# How can I repair a corrupt kernel if no others are installed?

Tags: 10.04, boot, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

I've been running Ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop for quite some time. When I went to boot it up this morning, BAM! kernel panic (which immediately lead to human panic) when loading the kernel.

So I've spent much of the day troubleshooting, and my current theory is that the FS is fine, but that the kernel image may be corrupt. Let's go with this current theory for the sake of this question, as I am interested how it is done.

How can I replace the kernel image if I have no bootable kernels?

Can I boot to a 10.04 live CD, copy the the vmlinuz-2.6.3x... to the HD and go from there?
Wouldn't I want to copy the initramfs as well, but configured for the desktop system?
Can I generate this from the live CD?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](http://askubuntu.com/q/28099/6969)

Comment: @Lekensteyn, yup, that looks like a good answer. Thanks for pointing that out. I will give the approach a shot and update here with the outcome.