# What does "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already" mean?

Tags: apt, apport

When installing a Linux kernel image package, I got, amongst other errors:

> No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Where  can I delete old reports so that Apport can resume doing its bug reporting magic again?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The crash files are gathered in `/var/crash`.

In a session, if apport collects information, there are also apport files in `/tmp/apport.appname...`.

Comment: so what does this inform me?

Answer (score 17):

When I received this error message, I found it had to do with the `/boot` partition being filled with many old kernel images and headers that were not removed after dist-upgrades. A temporary solution from [this launchpad bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/798414/comments/10) is quoted at the bottom of this post.

It's worth noting that Ubuntu is working on [a fix through Apt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/923876), which as of 2013-03-26 is implemented in Precise, but pending on Quantal.

> **Warning**: *removing kernel packages can be dangerous, and might even
>   leave your system unable to boot, so please don't do this if you don't
>   understand what is going on.*
>
> I fixed this on my system by removing some old kernels, that I am not
>   using any more.
>
> I checked what kernel I am using like this:
>
> ```
> uname -r
> ```
>
> This gave me a version number of a kernel I MUST NOT remove because I
>   am using it.
>
> Then I checked what kernels were installed like this:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove linux-<TAB>
> ```
>
> I.e. I typed "sudo apt-get remove linux-" and pressed the TAB key
>   twice to see a list of possible completions. I chose the linux-image-*
>   and linux-image-extra-* packages that contained versions of the kernel
>   that I was not running, and removed them like this:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic linux-image-3.5.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-3.5.0-19-generic
> ```
>
> The exact list of packages in the "remove" line might be different for
>   you - I found it out by doing what I describe at the top.
>
> Then I made sure the recently-downloaded kernel packages that failed
>   to configure were ok by running:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> ```
>
> **Warning**: *removing kernel packages can be dangerous, and might even
>   leave your system unable to boot, so please don't do this if you don't
>   understand what is going on.*

Comment: This is useful but people contemplating using it should remember that it applies only to (some) situations where this error occurs *in connection with a problem installing a kernel package*. If your problem package doesn't have `linux-` in its name, then this is almost certainly *not* the solution for you; if it does, then this very well might help a lot. Also, make sure not to remove *all* the kernels; if there's no bootable kernel, the OS won't start, and the procedures for reinstalling a kernel in a system that won't start are [a bit involved](http://askubuntu.com/q/28099/22949).

Comment: this was the correct heads-up for me. I removed old kernels and problem was solved.

Comment: Rather than removing images explicitly, which could be error prone, you should do `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Hello can you look at my question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299265/no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-has-already-been-reached-cant-instal