# 12.04 Error: apt-get fails

Tags: 12.04

Most of my apt-get fails, and I am suggested by Ubuntu to run 'sudo apt-get -f install' which gives this:

```
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-standard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3); however:
  Version of grub2-common on system is 1.99-21ubuntu3.1.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 1.99-21ubuntu3); however:
  Version of grub-pc-bin on system is 1.99-21ubuntu3.1.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already     
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.24.26); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.0.0-19-generic
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic
 friendly-recovery
 memtest86+
 ubuntu-standard
 grub-pc
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I do now.

Comment: Please update your System as per [below answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/172850/63025).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Recommended updates (precise-updates)" activated as software source:

[image: Screenshot of "software Sources"]

then run

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

`No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already`
means that apport is full of old error logs, so you have to clear it, so that `Apport` can start its error logging again.
To clear that, clear the following two paths:
The crash files are gathered in: `/var/crash`
In a session, if apport collects information, there are also apport files in: `/tmp/apport.appname...`

Now try again, this time Apport should atleast generate a goog error log for your problem, which you can possibly use to report/resolve the bug(or problem).

***Courtesy:*** [What does "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31667/no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-is-reached-already)