# getting error while installing any software or updating in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, software-installation

while installing anything or updating i get this error "The installation or removal of a software package failed." and details are below  :

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 445343 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace qbittorrent 3.1.x-0~4612-20131231~ubuntu12.04.1 (using .../qbittorrent_3.1.x-0~4619-20140103~ubuntu12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement qbittorrent ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.9) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/isc-dhcp-server.config: 10: /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server: Separate: not found
dpkg: error processing isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dhcp3-server:
 dhcp3-server depends on isc-dhcp-server; however:
  Package isc-dhcp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dhcp3-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qbittorrent (3.1.x-0~4619-20140103~ubuntu12.04.1) ...No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 isc-dhcp-server
 dhcp3-server
Error in function: 
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.9) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/var/lib/dpkg/info/isc-dhcp-server.config: 10: /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server: Separate: not found
dpkg: error processing isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dhcp3-server:
 dhcp3-server depends on isc-dhcp-server; however:
  Package isc-dhcp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dhcp3-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

while in actual software gets installed but gives the above error. i am using ubuntu 12.04 with gnome shell.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/31667/what-does-no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-is-reached-already-mean

Answer (score 0):

From the error log in your question I can assume that something wrecked is happening with your locales. (an not only).

Examine this file

```
cat /etc/default/locale
```

the content of this file should read

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

above is for English language. But no other line should be inside this file.

If other lines exist, edit the file and remove them all except from the `LANG` string.

If the file does not even exist then, create it and add the `LANG` string only.

In any case use an editor with root privileges.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/locale
```

after you edit and save, 
reconfigure some things.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales 
sudo update-locale
```

logout/login or reboot.

About the dhcp server, [read this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184351/95393). Some configuration files must exist. These files are listed in the answer with the default content.

Then try again

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```