# Running apt-get -f install, now in a loop

Tags: apt

I was installing a package (Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit) and was told there were dependencies not applied to my install. As advised I ran 'sudo apt-get -f install' to fix them, but ran out of space in /boot during the process. I freed up space in /boot but now, I can't apply anything because I'm in a loop of:

```
moodle:/boot$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  php-fpdf linux-headers-3.2.0-44-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic linux-  
  headers-3.2.0-44 linux-headers-3.2.0-51 linux-headers-3.2.0-52
  unzip libphp-magpierss mimetex smarty php5-curl libphp-snoopy 
  linux-image-3.2.0-51-    generic php5-xmlrpc libjs-yui libphp-pclzip zip
  linux-headers-3.2.0-51-generic php5-ldap linux-image-3.2.0-44-generic 
  linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 112 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
  linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.54.64); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.58.69.
linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.54.64); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.58.69.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered     while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions?

Regards,
  Gord

Comment: Look quite similar to: [this entry](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31667/what-does-no-apport-report-written-because-maxreports-is-reached-already-mean)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a space issue since I freed up space, I need to somehow resolve the dependency. linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic shows as already at the newest version when I try to do a install on that, so it's there...

Comment: You could try to reinstall linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic with: sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic

Answer (score -1):

try to run apt-get check, so that apt can verify if your box is OK and all package's dependencies are correctly satisfied

If your system isn't seriously broken, you'll be able to fix it with apt-get -f install. If its broken, you'll have to fix these dependencies by hand (I mean, using the dpkg command) before start using apt.

or maby

apt-get build-dep build-essential

aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade

will fix your system, i'v expirienced in the past that everytime i'm struggeling whit apt-get, installing build dep or build-essential fixes my issues.

Comment: All suggested commands failed with the same dependency error :(

Comment: then you have to do this manually whit dpkg

Comment: try to run sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-server && sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-server (apt-get is telling you that you need to install some stuff, but the stuff is already installed and the version is to "up to date") And this might force your system to install the correct decencies.

Comment: If that does not work, try to run sudo dpkq --remove linux-server amd then apt-get install linux-server to se if it fixes the issue.