#  Error: You need to load the kernel first in Grub

Tags: lubuntu, grub2

I have Lubuntu 11.10 installed on `/dev/sda3`, and Xubuntu 11.10 on `/dev/sda5`. A while ago, while being on Lubuntu, I made a mistake somewhere in creating a Live USB: by mistake, I installed a Live USB bootloader into `/dev/sda3`. This didn't result in any problem at that time.

Today, I updated the kernel. I had to restart Lubuntu. In Grub, Lubuntu suddenly didn't appear anymore, and I booted automatically in Xubuntu. I tried to run `update-grub` and tried to use `grub-customizer` to get Lubuntu back in Grub, but this didn't work. I ran `os-prober`, but it doesn't show me Lubuntu.

Then, I tried to add a new entry to `/etc/grub.d/` on `/dev/sda5` called `12_lubuntu`. It contained the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "Lubuntu"
cat << EOF
menuentry "Lubuntu" {
set root=(hd0,3)
linux /boot/vmlinuz
initrd /boot/initrd.img
}
EOF
```

After doing that, I ran `update-grub` and with `grub-customizer`, I wrote the Grub-configuration to MBR, that is: `/dev/sda`.

Suddenly, Lubuntu appeared in Grub. I tried to launch it, but when doing this, the following messages appeared:

```
Error: File not found
Error: You need to load the kernel first
```

The output of `ls -all` in `/dev/sda3` is as follows:

```
gijs@Gijs-PC:/media/9c715f68-f083-46ab-9d55-6139556f31d4$ ls -all
totaal 112
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 2011-11-25 23:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2011-11-26 10:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-11-22 22:17 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 2011-11-25 23:36 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-10-15 21:58 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2011-10-12 18:08 dev
drwxr-xr-x 146 root root 12288 2011-11-25 23:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2011-10-15 21:59 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    37 2011-11-25 23:35 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic-pae
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 2011-11-25 23:35 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 2011-11-22 22:17 lib
drwx------   2 root root 16384 2011-10-15 21:56 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2011-11-24 20:59 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-10-09 09:29 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 2011-11-24 17:15 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-10-09 09:29 proc
drwx------  13 root root  4096 2011-11-22 17:19 root
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2011-10-15 22:01 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-11-22 22:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-06-21 20:43 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-10-12 18:06 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2011-07-14 07:11 sys
drwxrwxrwt   8 root root  4096 2011-11-25 23:37 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 2011-10-12 18:06 usr
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4096 2011-11-25 23:37 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 2011-11-25 23:35 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic-pae
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 2011-11-25 23:35 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic
```

I've also found the old `30_os-prober_proxy` in `/dev/sda3/etc/grub.d`, which should contain the old boot stuff. It is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#THIS IS A GRUB PROXY SCRIPT
'/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/os-prober' | /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy "-*
-'Ubuntu, met Linux 3.0.0-12-generic-pae (on /dev/sda3)'
-'Ubuntu, met Linux 3.0.0-12-generic-pae (herstelmodus) (on /dev/sda3)'
+'Ubuntu, met Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (on /dev/sda3)' as 'Xubuntu'
-'Ubuntu, met Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (herstelmodus) (on /dev/sda3)'
+'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' as 'Windows 7'
"
```

How can I make Grub start Lubuntu again?

Comment: You should be aware that you can have LXDE and Xfce installed at the same time in the same Ubuntu installation, combining all the functionality of LXDE and Xfce for a lower total amount of used space (and far greater convenience in switching between them). To get fully-functional LXDE on an existing Ubuntu (or Xubuntu) system, install the `lubuntu-desktop` package. To get fully-functional Xfce on an existing Ubuntu (or Lubuntu) system, install the `xubuntu-desktop` package.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Exeleration-G - maybe I'm asking the obvious and I'm sure you've already tried this - but have you run the boot-repair process as per this community wiki?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Can you please post the output of the boot_info_script? http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've put the output of the boot_info_script here, because it would mess up the layout if I'd just paste it in the question.

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=205317&c=5351130

Comment: I've ran Boot-Repair, but it didn't help. I guessed that it didn't put the generated Grub in the MBR, so I put the generated Grub in the MBR using Grub Customizer. Boot-Repair gave a textual output as well, to be found on http://paste.ubuntu.com/752544/

Comment: @Exeleration-G - looks like you need to force grub to be reinstalled on /dev/sda3 - a good guide is this (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) - search for "Copy LiveCD Files" and you should be mounting /dev/sda3.  If this doesnt work - force the reinstallation of the kernel into /dev/sda3 as per this Q&A:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made the mistake of writing here that Lubuntu was installed on `/dev/sda3`, while it was in fact on `/dev/sda5`. Strangely enough, Grub asked to launch Xubuntu from `/dev/sda5`, so that caused my confusion. Applying your answers on `/dev/sda5` didn't help. Ostensibly, Grub was a mess, so I decided to reinstall `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5`. Thanks for your help though.

fossfreedom, I think that you've helped me most, and I think that your comments are the most usable for future readers. Please put the comments in an answer, so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A week ago, I've had the same problem another time, but now I fixed it myself. It turned out that the problem had nothing to do with the LiveUSB-install. What I had to do, was start `grub-customizer` from Xubuntu, click `File`, `Select Partition`, click `Next`, select Lubuntu's partition, and then click `Mount the selected filesystem`. I had the option to select submountpoints, but that wasn't necessary. I clicked `Apply`.

Right now, I had to check all the checkboxes that were available to be sure that I could start Lubuntu from Grub. Then I clicked `File`, `Save`, after that, I clicked `File`, `Install to MBR`.

I rebooted, and I could boot into Lubuntu again, the problem was solved.

If this doesn't solve your problem, I'd advice you to use the tools that fossfreedom mentions in another answer below.

Answer (score 3):

### Boot-Repair

The majority of grub boot issues can be resolved through using *boot-repair* - as [this community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) explains, you can install this on a liveCD/USB or directly in a working ubuntu install and it will attempt to find all O/S installs and repair the overall Grub MBR.

### Manual Grub2 Installation

If boot-repair fails to work its magic then the traditional manual grub2 installation method described in [this community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) should be investigated.

Search on that web-page for the section *Copy LiveCD Files*.  Replace the example `/dev/sdxy` statements with the partition that you have installed lubuntu in - for example `/dev/sda3`

If you are unsure which partition you have installed then you can run the Boot-info-script found on [SourceForge](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).

In the results look for partitions types of `ext4` or `ext3` - these are the common Ubuntu filesystems unless you previously elected to use something like `btrfs` or `reiserfs` etc.

### Kernel reinstallation

If the issue is a corrupt kernel installation then you can investigate reinstalling the kernel from a live CD.  This is described in this excellent [AskUbuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

By installing the kernel correctly, Grub should be able to see the Lubuntu installation correctly.

Comment: Is `boot-repair` even maintained? According to https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/support: "Unfortunately, this project hasn't indicated the best way to get help" - and https://github.com/yannmrn/boot-repair hasn't been touched in 6 years

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second line (the one starting with `echo`). You might also have to add a root-parameter to the kernel, like this:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
```

After that run `update-grub` again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this did not help. I still get the following messages:

`Error: File not found`

`Error: You need to load the kernel first`.

I've updated the question to show the output of ls -all in `/dev/sda3`. Hope that this helps you to help me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a live cd to boot into the system and then chrooting to the lubuntu system using these commands.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/abc
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/abc
sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /mnt/abc/dev
sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /mnt/abc/proc
sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /mnt/abc/sys
sudo chroot /mnt/abc
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I think this would fix your problem, if you don't want to have lubuntu loader in the MBR you can install grub in /dev/sda3 and then use `update-grub` using xubuntu. That would work.