# error: you need to load kernel first

Tags: grub2, kernel, boot-failure

I made a clean install on my Sony Vaio laptop, of Ubuntu 11.10 and when the installation was ready, it prompted to remove the USB I was installing the distro from, and press enter to reboot. After this reboot the first thing I got was the following error:

```
error: couldn't read file
error: you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue..
```

After that it throws me back to the Grub select screen:

```
Ubuntu, with linux 3.0.0-14-generic-pae
recovery mode
previous Linux versions (none since I made a clean install)
memory test
```

If I choose the first option it shows only a black screen and never loads anything.
If I reboot the same thing happens.

Could I repair this using boot-repair?
Is there any other way?

Note: I know nothing about Linux code so I am a total noob on this one

Update: boot-repair did not help

Grub.cfg here: http://pastebin.com/GKLuDuhM

Boot Info Script: http://pastebin.com/indARkKJ

Comment: Hi - please look at the Q&A and pastebin the output from the script that is suggested to be run.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/90045/how-do-i-investigate-boot-and-partition-issues

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have pasted the info here: http://pastebin.com/indARkKJ

Comment: Some possible solutions have been posted earlier in [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82759/error-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first-in-grub). These might help you.

Comment: I have tried the boot-repair, mind you, I dont understand much of the other stuff posted there... :(

Comment: you have "nomodeset" in your recovery boot options but "acpi=off" in the normal boot options.  Why?  If you select "recovery mode" what happens?  If you press "e" on the first option and change "nomodeset" for "acpi=off" (or just remove "nomodeset") followed by CTRL+X  to boot, what happens?

Comment: If i select recovery mode the same thing happens. I removed the nomodeset but again the same thing happened. 

I do not know why those setting are like this, probably after I used the boot-repair-disk?

Comment: I tried a new clean install as a sledgehammer approach because of my lack of knowledge, but nothing worked. Since when I had 8.10 it worked fine...

I dont know whats the case? Could it be faulty HDD?

Comment: How can I mark this as solved? Adter a lot of search I diagnosed that the problem was a faulty HDD. This came with the help of some guys of the Grub community in IRC.

Thanks everyone for their amazing help! Wish you well!

Comment: Oh, I almost missed it as it was hidden behind "show 3 more". I will add it as an answer to the question.

Comment: What HDD was that?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your disk drive, it means that GRUB really can't read the file `/boot/vmlinuz...`. You can check the file by trying to copy it or the disk with `badblocks` command as suggested on http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-hardware/7228767 (in Russian).