# Reinstall GRUB to partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mbr

Recently my BCD corrupted, so I reinitialised it from a LiveUSB, and added my Ubuntu partition back to it. Unfortunately the kernel isn't loading, so I thought to reinstall GRUB. The results below show what happened when this was attempted.

Initial error was:

> "Failed to get canonical path of /cow"

`mount`ing—including `--bind` of `/dev` stuff—the partition then `chroot`ing in got over that error, but left me with a:

> "error: will not proceed with blocklists"

PS: Here is my boot-info log: http://www.pastebin.ca/3134305

Comment: Do not run Boot-Repair's auto fix. That installs grub to the MBR of every drive. You want to install grub to the MBR of sdb. You show a copy there and in the partition boot sector of sdb1, but installing to a partition boot sector is not recommended by grub. And it is not required since you can install to sdb. You also have a lot of kernels & need to houseclean.

Comment: I tried their autofix, I tried installing to the MBR of sdb, and I tried installing directly to my Ubuntu partition. All failed to let me boot into Ubuntu. Specifically I would like the BCD to be my main bootloader, and grub (or similar) to be installed on my Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I would not use command grub-install too here, instead it can happen that command update-grub2 is sufficient.

Comment: What is this BCD?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a total reorganization is the most easy solution, so I suggest :

Completely rebuild your disk layout and keep it as simple as possible.
You should place all boot loaders and operating systems on one disk.

1. Backup the partitions you want to keep (recommended : Clonezilla).
2. Create a new partition table on all disks (recommended : GParted).
3. Create new partitions and prepare them for restoration process.
4. Boot from Clonezilla live media again and restore the partitions.
5. Boot from Windows install media and rebuild Windows BCDstore.
6. Boot from ubuntu install media and reinstall the GRUB bootloader.

If you want Windows bootloader to be default turn around steps 5 and 6.
In this case you must install GRUB to the root partition of the ubuntu OS.

Then you can to use bcdedit to add the Linux partitions to the BCDstore.
Assuming you are having advanced knowledge I ommitted more details !

Answer (score 0):

First I fixed a bunch of disk errors on a potentially unrelated partition (but maybe `/boot` was mounted there?):

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 /dev/sda1
```

Then I created a partition `/dev/sda4` and installed a bootloader [actually an entire OS] served from that partition, on `/dev/sda`.

FInally I was able to boot back into my Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score -1):

**its seems your kernel is broken and needs repair here is your solution waiting for you**  [click me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82759/error-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first-in-grub)