# How to restore deleted files in /boot? (vmlinuz missing, system does not boot)

Tags: boot, kernel, restore

I mistakenly erased one the `vmlinuz` files in my `/boot` directory. However, I made a backup of `/boot` inside `/tmp`, just to be sure.

Consequently, I cannot boot up, as I get the missing vmlinuz file error. So I booted up using a live USB, but when I got into the `/boot` dir in my hard drive (sda5), it's completely empty. If I copy the files from `/tmp/boot` to that `/boot` directory, I still cannot boot up.

How can I restore those files to the appropriate directory?

Comment: Even [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/150691/37165) asked similar question, its answer only explained how to reinstall the packages to restore boot files *without* explaining `chroot` steps since the OP there knew how to do by himself. In contrast, the current question is explicitly asking how to restore boot files i.e. using Live USB, in which answer should include steps to do `chroot`. So I see this question as unique and voted +1.

Comment: Related: [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`vmlinuz` is the Linux kernel image itself (the z indicates that it is compressed).

Reinstalling the kernel package that is currently referenced by [linux-image-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic) (or your [HWE kernel](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/40581)) and probably [linux-singed-image-generic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-signed-image-generic) in UEFI secure boot environments should solve your issue.

## Reinstalling a kernel from a chroot

Preferably boot live media of the same version and mount the partition of your installation (you can do that with Nautilus, it will be something like `/media/ubuntu/…` then) or your `/boot` partition (this will be a bit more complex). This will be `${my_installation}` in the following instructions.

Look into `/lib/modules/` of your installation (`${my_installation}/lib/modules/`) for the particular kernel versions that were installed and pick the latest version number you can find, this is referenced as `${kernel_ver}` in the following instructions, in my test VM it was 3.16.0-46.

As I stated in a comment before, the procedure is very similar to reinstalling Grub in chroot, so let me quote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/40581) with some slight modifications:

> 4. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:
>
>    ```
>     for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "${my_installation}$i"; done
>    ```
> 5. `chroot` into your Ubuntu install:
>
>    ```
>     sudo chroot ${my_installation}
>    ```
> 6. At this point, you're in your install, not the live session, and running as root. …

Now reinstall your kernel (the *`signed`* package is for UEFI secure boot):

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-${kernel_ver}-generic linux-signed-image-${kernel_ver}-generic
```

Check the `/boot` directory if the `initrd` for this kernel is still missing. To generate it manually run:

```
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-${kernel_ver}-generic ${kernel_ver}-generic
```

My example:

```
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic 3.16.0-46-generic
```

Then run `update-grub` like in the quoted answer so that you can be sure that the "new" kernel and initrd are included.

If you need to reinstall Grub too you can follow the the remaining steps. Remember that these instructions were written for MBR, if you have UEFI (where bootloaders from different OSes shouldn't overwrite each other) you need to check that `grub-efi-amd64-bin` is installed install before reinstalling Grub.

---

Comment: But I cannot do this from a USB live image, can I?

Comment: Oops you are right, but is should be possible the same way as [reinstalling Grub via chroot](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/40581) only that you are installing something slightly different. The live image version must match your installation.

Comment: @clearkimura Okay just reproduced it in a VM and updated my answer.

Comment: @NVaughan The answer has been updated, so follow the steps and feedback to `LiveWireBT` if this now works for you?

Comment: hi there, I get an error when I try to apt-get install...
error is: cannot stat 'usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-wheezy/extlinux/memtest.bin' no such file or directory
failed to process /etc/kernal/postrm.d

Comment: @PaulPreibisch You can find the package that provides a file with [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/482/40581). It's syslinux-themes-debian-wheezy in 14.04 here on my machine.

Comment: This was key to solving my broken (unbootable) installation after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04. Thanks!