# Accidentally removed kernel and basic drivers (internet touchpad graphics not working)

Tags: command-line, apt, kernel, touchpad, sed

I had been having low storage issues on my root partition so I tried out some cleaning advice from this forum, including ([Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)) and also (https://maryrosecook.com/blog/post/freeing-disk-space-on-your-linux-server), and the following ordered list of (I realised, dangerous) commands:

```bsh
apt-get autoclean

sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*

sudo du -h --max-depth=1

dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge

sudo dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge

sudo dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -rm | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get purge

sudo shutdown -rf
```

In particular, I think what messed things up was the long 'sudo dpkg...' command, which is supposed to remove old kernels; I think it could've removed the kernel and some important drivers.

Now, I have a dual windows boot, but my grub has disappeared, in the sense that it automatically goes to ubuntu(even though i can access windows through F2 bios); to try and fix the kernel, I followed ([How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)) with little success, meaning linux-image-generic is installed now but that didn't fix things.

The experienced issues in Ubuntu are:
-Screen Resolution stuck at 800x600
-Not recognising any internet peripherals, including internal wifi, external wifi adapter, ethernet
-touchpad not working
--The rest of the system is working, it seems.

other solutions i could try are using the boot-repair tool, but without internet i don't know how to install it(same with removed packages although i might be able to do that from live usb), and i am not sure how to use it/whether that could help.

Also, should I try following the answer in ([How to restore deleted files in /boot? (vmlinuz missing, system does not boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696409/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-boot-vmlinuz-missing-system-does-not-boot))?

P.S. I have home and root folders on separate partitions

Comment: Think the easiest way would be to reinstall system on root.  Backup home in case something goes wrong.  Should be able to backup from live system.  Root should be about 20GBs plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have a look at the packages you removed 
by looking at the dpkg & apt log:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log 
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

or

```
xdg-open /var/log/dpkg.log 
xdg-open  /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to reinstall all the removed packages from Live USB and your answer helped finding those packages. i also fixed grub with boot-repair