# Test tar archive of linux drive on the same pc

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, tar

**Introduction**

I have kubuntu 20 on my oc. I created a backup of kubuntu(22 gb) using Kbackup in form of tar

file image of my kde drive(sda2)

**What I want**

I wish to test this backup on the same computer by creating an empty ext4 partition on the same pc(sda5)

**What Happened**
I successfully created a second **ext4** partition. After editing fstab file by  adjusting the right UUID and applying bootloader, my boot menu simply does not show the twin kde. I even copied the partition table found in **/root** of
***parent kde***. This partition has now **bootflag** too.

Here  are the boot-repair paste-bin and other info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zbp74KWn3R/ (Note that Partition info recognizes sda2 as having boot but a **no kernel** with sda5) I already have kernels copied in `usr/src` of `/dev/sda5`.

Output of blkid

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="a8bc0529-436e-48eb-9100-b64d24bb493d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="88989976-f24a-b145-822e-9582051b94e
```

`fstab` file of new /sda5 partition:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a8bc0529-436e-48eb-9100-b64d24bb493d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
#UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
UUID=D492-A6EC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

Kindly guide me on this issue.

**Edit**

I excluded following directories from backup

```
--exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"
```

**Edit2**
I have discovered that i have also excluded "/boot". Currently my /sda5 has a lonely **"efi"** folder in it.

**Edit3**
After copying the /boot folder, the grub and paste-bin successfully integrates /sda5.

I selected /sda5 and **OOPS!, I was booted back to /sda2.** It appears that the copied boot file **loop me back to sda2** instead of **entrance to sda5**.

Kindly guide me how to regenerate boot files of /sda5 so that i can log on to it to test it on my own system.

Comment: FYI:  Kubuntu (along with all Ubuntu) uses a *year.month* format for releases, so there is no 2020.  It looks like you're using 20.10, or the 2020-October release.   (Ubuntu does have a different product range that uses *year* only, eg. Ubuntu Core 20, but it's for specialist purposes and *year* only releases are *snap* only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally accomplished **testing my cloned system** in the partiton of the same computer as was **original one**.
In my case I created a tar backup of linux filesystem with excluding **--exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/boot") using kbackup**.

One must never forget to include **Root** as it contains the partition table without which, entire backup is simply useless.
**Boot** must be backed up separately, because it redirects the system to load exact location i.e /dev/sdaX as i learned from my experience. You may have to generate boot grub files separately if you are using a different location other than original one for **cloning linux file-system**.

**Then I created an inetrnal ext4 partiton to test the tar as I do not have another laptop and do not intend to guinea pig my own system.**
I edited fstab file in routine. Creating swap file is easy.

On my system it was named as **/dev/sda5**(test drive).

Then instead of using livecd I used my own root system, which was intended to be cloned

First I mounted the test drive on /mnt/Test(say)

sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/Test

And untar my entire linux filesystem to that folder **Test**

Following, I created following empty directories that were excluded from **tar backup**

sudo mkdir temp && sudo mkdir proc && sudo mkdir sys && sudo mkdir dev && sudo mkdir boot

Then i copied following boot files from my **own boot system** to the **cloned system** as

sudo cp -r /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-25-generic  /mnt/Test/boot

sudo cp -r /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic  /mnt/Test/boot

sudo cp -r /boot/vmlinuz  /mnt/Test/boot

sudo cp -r /lib/modules/5.8.0-25-generic /mnt/Test/lib/modules/

sudo cp -r /lib/modules/5.8.0-41-generic /mnt/Test/lib/modules/

Then I follwed advice from [How to restore deleted files in /boot? (vmlinuz missing, system does not boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696409/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-boot-vmlinuz-missing-system-does-not-boot)

for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/Test$i"; done

chroot /mnt/Test

mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-25-generic 5.8.0-25-generic

mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic 5.8.0-41-generic

Then i updated grub both inside cloned system and my original system.
sudo update-grub

Create mnt directory if missing

sudo mkdir -m 755 /mnt

In order to be sure if you have indeed landed in cloned system as it is hard to tell the difference from the original one, make a text file in  $HOME directory of cloned system from original one  listing some text"(Big Brother is watching)".