# How can we restore If all kernel has removed by mistaken it has RAID10

Tags: grub2, partitioning, kernel, mount, raid

how we can restore the server if we removed the all kernels, and I have the RAID 10. in this case I try to recover with live-cd but I am not able to mounting partition because 
I have RAID10 partitions, when I mounting this partitions unknown filesystem raid.

mount /dev/sdXY /mnt -t ext4

is this correct command for mount raid10 partitions ?

Answer (score 0):

You're following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/28100/449).

If you're using RAID you need to replace step 2 (`mount /dev/sdXY /mnt`) with a command to mount your RAID array.

If it's mdadm, first find out what your mdadm drive is called. The simplest way to do this is to look at the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`. It'll be called something like `md126`.  And then just substitude that into the process: `sudo mount /dev/md126 /mnt`

If it's dmraid, it'll probably be lurking in `/dev/mapper/` (run `ls /dev/mapper/` to see) and then substitude that in: `sudo mount /dev/mapper/1231438jkb4k2g4h2b34 /mnt`

After you've got it mounted on /mnt - just continue the process as if it were a normal drive.

Comment: is there any way to install kernel without live cd...

Comment: There are different live environments (USB, net boot) but a simple CD is hard to beat.