# After deleting some old kernel

Tags: kernel, software-installation, dpkg

I deleted some essential kernels parts to enlarge the free space on my boot partition. First I proceed as in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels). However the problem is not exactly the same as in the link (see answer from Eliah below). What I tried first was the following, first output of my partition scheme:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST3500418AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  535MB   535MB   primary  ext4            boot
 2      535MB   5914MB  5379MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 3      5914MB  106GB   100GB   primary  ext4
 4      106GB   500GB   394GB   primary  ext4


Model: WD 5000AAC External (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  500GB  500GB  primary  ext4


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I have the boot partition on `sda1` , `sda2` is my swap partition, `sda3` is my root directory and `sda4` is my home partition. I followed the instruction on the second answer (by Eliah). This means:

1.

```
     ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

2. Then I chrooted:

   ```
       ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
       root@ubuntu:/# mount -t proc none /proc
       root@ubuntu:/# mount -t sysfs none /sys
       root@ubuntu:/# mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
       root@ubuntu:/# export HOME=/root
       root@ubuntu:/# export LC_ALL=C
   ```
3. I tried to install new kernel:

   ```
    apt-get update
    apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
   ```

Here I get the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (3.8.0-29.42) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic)
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-imNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
             age:
 linux-image depends on linux-image-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@ubuntu:/# 


umount /proc || umount -lf /proc
umount /sys /dev/pts
exit
sudo umount /mnt/dev /mnt
```

I also tried to uninstall everything and run

```
apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

and of course

```
update-grub
```

I'm still getting the memtest while booting. As Eliah pointed out, the above solution does not apply in my case. So I followed the instructions in his answer below. However this does not solve the problem. I got the following outputs:

```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@ubuntu:/# mount -t proc none /proc
root@ubuntu:/# mount -t sysfs none /sys
root@ubuntu:/# mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
root@ubuntu:/# export HOME=/root
root@ubuntu:/# export LC_ALL=C
```

then running `apt-get update` followed by the suggested:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -y --purge --reinstall install linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/43.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'initramfs-tools' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 251414 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic 3.8.0-29.42 (using .../linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic_3.8.0-29.42_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Unpacking replacement linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic ...
Preparing to replace linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic 3.8.0-29.42 (using .../linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic_3.8.0-29.42_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic ...
Preparing to replace linux-image-generic 3.8.0.29.47 (using .../linux-image-generic_3.8.0.29.47_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-image-generic ...
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (3.8.0-29.42) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic
 linux-image-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@ubuntu:/#
```

Comment: @EliahKagan If I follow the instructions I get the following issue, see my edited question

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all the details of what happened? The forum topic you linked to contains a variety of information and it's not clear which specific challenge you've come up against.

Comment: Does apt-get work?

Comment: @EliahKagan I edited my question as you said. I hope everything is clear now. I followed exactly your answer, however there was a problem using apt-get -y linux-image-generic.

Comment: @Dillmo Yes, I can run for example apt-get update etc, but there is the error message (see my edited question) if I want to install new linux-image.

Comment: I also tried to uninstall 'linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic' and reinstall everything again. After that I also run 'update-grub'. However, while booting it starts again the memtest

Comment: @EliahKagan Do you know how I can solve this problem? I followed exactly your intructions but can still not boot. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1):

[The answers there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels) are written for situations where there are no kernels because the packages that provide them have been removed.

Your situation is similar but a little different. It seems like what has happened on your system is that there are no kernels because their files have been manually deleted (or deleted by some automated process *other* than package deinstallation). It seems that, as far as the package manager is concerned, you still have kernels installed.

To solve this, it *might* be sufficient simply to tell the package manager to *reinstall* the kernel package.

You ran this command:

```
apt-get -y install linux-image-generic
```

Using the same procedure (including the `apt-get update` command before it), try *replacing* that `apt-get -y install` command with this one:

```
apt-get -y --purge --reinstall install linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic linux-image-generic
```

(The `--purge` flag is optional, as this problem is not related to systemwide configuration files. But it shouldn't hurt.)

That will uninstall the packages that are not working (due to deleted files), then reinstall them, ensuring that all their files are copied from the package archives. It shouldn't depend on any package files being present, so it should work even though some package files appear to have been manually deleted.

`linux-image-generic` is a metapackage; installing it causes the latest stable kernel for your system to be installed, because `linux-image-generic` declares the packages providing that kernel as dependencies. Stipuating that `linux-image-generic` is to be reinstalled "from scratch" does not necessarily cause all of its dependencies to be reinstalled, which is why I've listed its relevant dependencies explicitly in the command above.

I got their names (`linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic` and `linux-image-extra-3.8.0-29-generic`) from the output you included in your question. Someone else experiencing this problem will not necessarily want to stipulate exactly those packages for installation, but should instead see what packages `linux-image-generic` depends on, and explicitly reinstall *at least* the package that is missing files.

Thus, the *key* part of the output that led me to suggest this solution was:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (3.8.0-29.42) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic)
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-29-generic (--configure):
```

**It's possible this won't work.** That could happen if the packages are broken in a way that prevents the package manager from *uninstalling* them. If that or any other problems occur, then please update your question with details.

(For people besides the author of *this* question--if that happens and the information here doesn't enable you to solve it, post a new question with as many details as possible, or add details to your question if you've already posted one about the problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, see my edit (edit 2 for eliah). Similar issue

Comment: I also edited my question to clarify what the actual problem is. Again, thanks for your patience. Maybe the "This question may already have an answer here" should be removed, since my problem is different.

Comment: Have you seen my updated question? Should I provide more details? If so let me know. Thanks for your help

Comment: strange thing is, that now it uses the following kernel: `root@ubuntu:/# uname -r 3.5.0-17-generic`. So the ouput of uname -r is the 3.5.0-17.

Comment: @math It uses that kernel since you applied [that solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/337990/22949)? If so, I'd guess that you can upgrade the kernel just by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` (both after booting into the system normally, as whatever kernel was successfully installed should allow).

Answer (score 1):

A friend solved the problem. He suggested the following, which worked for me:

```
apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common 
apt-get install grub-common grub-pc 
update-grub
```

Comment: Good idea! I had not thought of reinstalling the GRUB package (which is what was done here, and is not the same as the more common operation of reinstalling GRUB to the MBR). A number of problems installing and uninstalling kernels relate to scripts that modify GRUB, so it makes sense that this solution would work. I'm glad this worked. By the way, the first two commands could probably be done with one: `apt-get --purge --reinstall grub-common grub-pc`

Answer (score 0):

Using the information above, I used the following

```
uname -r
```

Lets call whatever the output of the above command **PUMPKIN**

Then I typed:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

I looked through the output of this list and noted the linux-image-PUMPKIN

Anything else that was NOT my linux-image-PUMPKIN, could be removed by completing the command as it applies to you:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-(your non-PUMKIN entry goes here)
```

then a

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-grub2
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And I was good after a reboot.