# How to install 'precise' linux-image package from livecd after I accidentally deleted all kernels?

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg, live-cd

I had some strange issues installing `sudo apt-get install linux-image-server` and for some reason apt-get was trying to install two different versions of the kenrel, the real issue was that I removed the previous kernel.

The PC got rebooted (I work with two PC's with KVM, pressed Alt + Ctrl + Del while thinking I was in windows getting Ubuntu to reset itself) and walla! I have only meme test in grub, great...

Any idea how I can install a kernel image using liveCD and apt-get ? or am I better with downloading what I need from Ubuntu package site and then how do I use dpkg to install it with a liveCD on my local machine ? Somehow `chroot` to it from the live CD ?

Comment: Could you write the exact error?

Comment: not really, i can't boot into my system anymore since i have no kernel image....
my original question was if anyone knew how i could install new one using apt-get\dpkg from a rescue disk\live cd.

Comment: If I had understood your question first, I would have guided you to [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](http://askubuntu.com/q/28099/169736)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course like any a little hard to solve the question in stack overflow sites I had to manage on my own.

1. start a live CD, I used ubuntu 12.10 installation.

   1. `sudo -i`
2. mount your system under /mnt.
3. use `mount -o bind` to bind /proc, /sys and /dev to the mounted system.
4. `cp $(readlink /etc/resolv.conf) /mnt` --> this will make sure u can use the networking...
5. `chroot /mnt bash`
6. `service networking restart`
7. `dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l|grep "^iU *linux-image")`

After that I could install a specific kernel version using `apt-get install linux-image-3.0.xx-yy` and restart the system with a new normal image, my main problem was that for some reason the -19 version of the kernel with the 'extra' package failed to install together. Installing just the kernel alone solved the problem.