# Accidentally uninstalled all kernels

Tags: kernel, mount, chroot

I'm running the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS LAMP server. I got an error stating that my root directory was full after running an apt-get dist-upgrade, so following the instructions I found online, I uninstalled some of the old kernels using apt-get. However, I somehow accidentally uninstalled all of the kernels. My system won't reboot now.

I found a thread from 2011 about resolving this issue
[How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

But when I try to follow the instructions, they don't work for me.

When I do this:

`sudo parted -l`

I get this:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   2000GB  2000GB  extended
 5      257MB   2000GB  2000GB  logical                lvm


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.

Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

I don't understand why partition 1 is ext2 since this was a fresh install of 12.04 LTS, but I did this command as instructed:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

Then I tried this command:

`sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

and it said it couldn't find the mount point.

So, I did this:

`mkdir /mnt/dev`

and then it did the mount.

Okay, so now I'm ready for chroot per the instructions:

`sudo chroot /mnt`

And I get this:

`chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`

I apologize in advance, but I don't know enough about linux to figure out what's going on here. Could someone please help me? It will take me a long time to reinstall everything on my server.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your answer. When I enter

```
sudo pvs
```

I get:

```
PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize PFree  
/dev/sda5  HOP-Server lvm2 a-   1.82t 136.00m
```

Then, I enter

```
sudo lvdisplay /dev/HOP-Server
```

and get this:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/HOP-Server/root
  VG Name                HOP-Server
  LV UUID                feUsjU-HFHi-WFre-322J-SlWF-0J1K-zpiTQX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                1.81 TiB
  Current LE             474993
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/HOP-Server/swap_1
  VG Name                HOP-Server
  LV UUID                tuJSFw-EKU4-oeLI-A934-srj2-DA2L-VqZtYr
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                7.20 GiB
  Current LE             1843
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

That's slightly different from your example, but I presume that I should enter

```
sudo mount /dev/HOP-Server/root /mnt  **UPDATED**
```

But when I do, I get this:

```
mount: special device /dev/HOP-Server/root does not exist
```

**UPDATE: ** I used this web page to help me mount the file system partition:

```
http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html
```

After that, I was able to follow the rest of the original instructions with no errors. However, when I reboot, the only options are to start two versions of the memory test utility. I rebooted the live CD again and followed the instructions again. When I got to the apt-get for the kernel, it said that it's up to date.

**UPDATE:** Okay, I mounted the partitions again, and I can see that in /root is a file named initrd.img-3.2.0-56-generic. IIRC, that's the latest kernel. I ran update-grub, but it gives me the error, "cannot find a device for /".

**UPDATE:** After another search, I found this:

```
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems:Cannot_Find_A_Device_For_boot/grub
```

I followed that procedure, and it didn't get any errors. However, now when I boot, I get this:

```
error: ELF header smaller than expected
grub rescue>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your Ubuntu seems to be using a LVM as its root. The ext2 partition you mounted contains the bare necessities to make your system able to boot and mount the lvm, the rest – including `bash` – is stored there.

In order to find the LVM volume containing your data, you need the *lvm2* package, which is not installed on a live system. Thus, install it.

`sudo apt-get install lvm2`

Find the volume group containing your root partition by listing all volume groups.

`sudo pvs`

The output should look like

```
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree  
/dev/sda2  vg1  lvm2 a--  1,64t 236,91g
```

The second column contains the volume group's name, in this case `vg1`. With that, you can get information about the volumes contained in that group by issuing

`sudo lvdisplay /dev/vg1`

The output will look like

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg1/lv1
LV Name                lv1
VG Name                vg1
LV UUID                kE8qXE-bI4u-NLzZ-u37A-wZfx-NtaU-57PqRj
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time , 
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                1000,00 GiB
Current LE             256000
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:0
```

You are looking for the LV name, in this case `lv1`. In case there's just one volume, that should be your root drive. Otherwise, mount them all and see which one contains your system's data.

Mounting the volume is as easy as

`sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /mnt`

Once you've done that, you should be good to continue with the instructions from the thread you've found.

**Update**: As mentioned in the comments, since you are using a separate boot partition (`/dev/sda1`), you will have to mount it to `/mnt/boot/`. The second answer in the thread you've found contains some more details on that.

**Update 2**: The latest error usually indicates that something is wrong with your grub installation. If you have access to a remote GUI, you might try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If that doesn't help or you only have a terminal, I'd advise the creation of a new thread focused on this new problem.

Comment: Nice answer @drc (and nice editing of the question) - since the instructions the poster is following presumably don't mention how to handle a separate boot partition, should we include that they will likely need to add an extra step of making a `/mnt/boot` directory and mounting /dev/sda1 there?

Comment: Thanks, and good thinking with `/boot/`. Just checked the instructions and lucky for us, the second answer already contains a section about dealing with a separate boot partition. Added a hint to look at that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @drc. I appreciate the prompt answer. Unfortunately, I had a problem. A comment won't let me enter enough information, so I'm hoping it is okay for me to enter my results as an answer. I apologize if this is not how I should enter the information.

Comment: Just add the results in your original post. That should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @drc. I went back and did that, and hopefully formatted it better this time.

Comment: @drc I made some progress, but still can't reboot. Details in the question.