# USB Keyboard & Mouse Stopped Working (Ubuntu 14 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, usb, keyboard, mouse

I've been using Ubuntu 14 LTS on my work desktop, laptop, and home desktop without any problems. Does anyone know what I can do?

**What Works:**

- Keyboard on Boot
- Keyboard in BIOS
- Keyboard/Mouse on LiveCD
- GRUB Selection Menu
- Keyboard/Mouse Works on other OS's

**What Doesn't work:**

- Login screen keyboard and mouse

**Symptoms:**

- Stopped working for no apparent reason. (Possibly the built in software-updater changed something)
- Internet Message pops up saying cannot connect to internet (Not sure why, works on LiveCD)
- Blinking cursor on input field stops blinking after a few seconds.

**Tried:**

- Unplugging keyboard + mouse (Both are using USB 2.0)
- Made sure BIOS has Legacy USB Support on
- Tried different USB ports
- Browsing sites for a solution for a few hours, I cannot find a clear answer.

I have Linux Recovery options with several header versions, I have not tried using an older one. However, I am trying to repair the most current.

Comment: What is output of `uname -r` ?

Comment: 3.13.0-32-generic when I choose advanced options to get it working. But 3.13.0-34 does not work with keyboard/mouse (So I cant get to terminal in that state).

Comment: I hit this booting a 4.9 kernel in ubuntu 16.10.  I followed [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels) to install a 4.8 kernel (from a linux mint live boot), and was able to recover my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I booted ubuntu with kernel `3.13.0-32-generic` (Not the recovery mode), and I did a software update (Software Updater Application) and this seemed to fix it.

I also ran `sudo apt-get update`

I have no idea how or why this happened, but it seemed to fix it.

**Cliff notes:**

- I am using XServer for video even though I have an ATI Card
- I have not manually downloaded any extra linux kernels.