# USB Keyboard & Mouse Stopped Working (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I have the same problem like him ([USB Keyboard & Mouse Stopped Working (Ubuntu 14 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512430/usb-keyboard-mouse-stopped-working-ubuntu-14-lts))

It happend after nothing (no possible reason), I mean no updates or software changes were running before a system restart.

A timepart solution seems to be changing in the grub menu the run ubuntu in old kernel version (oldest helped me only).

But this is not the first time (last time I completly reinstalled Ubuntu).

This is very annoying problem.

Who can help to make a long therm solution? (Mouse and keyboard via USB).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. :/