# Mouse and keyboard stopped working altogether on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, 16.10, thinkpad

I have upgraded from 16.04. to 16.10 on a ThinkPad X230.

Everything went well. I used the machine for a whilem then went into the BIOS and disabled the touchpad because I want to use the trackpoint only.

When I rebooted, I had no keyboard or mouse in Ubuntu. The keyboard works fine in the BIOS on in recovery (console). The keyboard, touchpad, trackpad work fine on other OSes or with a LiveUSB of 16.04 and 16.10. A USB mouse or keyboard won't work on my 16.10, but will work in other OSes or LiveUSB.

I don't know where to look anymore. I tried what this suggested: [Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on login screen, no keyboard or mouse working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837003/ubuntu-16-04-freezes-on-login-screen-no-keyboard-or-mouse-working#837219) but to no avail.

Where should I look to understand what's going on, and how to fix?

Comment: Did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/512430/usb-keyboard-mouse-stopped-working-ubuntu-14-lts?rq=1

Comment: Yes I did, no luck.