# Network, usb and unity not working after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, upgrade, usb

I had a dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.

My update manager started to do weird things a while ago. It didn't get any new updates and it crashed a thousand times when I clicked on "upgrade now" to ubuntu 14. Then I always tried to report a bug from the dialog shown and it NEVER worked.

I had to upgrade so I could install some packages that only work on 13.10 and further. As I couldn't do it with the update manager, I tried with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After this I rebooted and that was it. Nothing works. I get a black background after the session starts (I had it configured to automatically start with my user). Network doesn't work, I get a "network disconnected" message as a welcome dialog so I can't use any online solutions.

USB ports are also broken, so I can't use another computer to download the solution.

Using a regular keyboard I ran a terminal and tried some of the solutions I found online, most of them need network connection or some sort of package download.

I didn't find any IOMMU options in my BIOS setup, doing some research I noticed my mother board is not on the list of compatible ones (it's an ASUS M5A87).

Then I tried:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

It returned some errors that I couldnt catch, but the result is that everything is the same (or worse, I honestly don't know).

I also tried to run an older linux kernel to see if it works, but I get "failed to start session "ubuntu" " before and after the login menu (I get this message before and after I try to login).

I know there are a lot of details I am not giving, but I'm getting a bit desperate, I can't find answers for this problem and I wanted to start this question as soon as possible. Ask for any details that can help.

Of course, everything is working like a charm from windows 7, so no hardware issues here.

Comment: You should follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/28100/196592) answer to some extent. When you have entered the chroot. Instead or in addition to installing a newer kernel install all needed packages.

Comment: After all this issues, if I get a live CD in my tray is not going to be to repair Ubuntu, it'll be to do a fresh install and burn the remainings to ashes. Thanks, but this is taking too much effort and it's not worth repairing if it's more dificult than installing some other distro.

Comment: Could you try re-running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, and getting the errors?