# Trouble loading ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Trying to load ubuntu 14 on a laptop and get the message need to load kernel first.Found kernel.org but can't seem to unzip it.now using xp but would like to switch to linux.

Comment: Are trying to boot a live-USB or live-CD?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the grub issues can be resolved using boot-repair! To know more about this, visit the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) it explains that, you can install this on a liveCD/USB or directly in a working ubuntu install and it will attempt to find all O/S installs and repair the overall Grub MBR.

To re install the kernel, follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

HTH!