# Unable to boot to encrypted root partition after Ubuntu 14.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, mount, encryption, lenovo

I am running a Lenovo T440p with a clean install of Ubuntu. No dual booting. Over the weekend I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. There were some package install errors that led to Ubuntu being booted in 'low-graphics' mode. I ultimately fixed the package issues by deleting my installed cisco VPN client. I was then able to do an *apt-get update* and *apt-get upgrade*.

Here is where all that backstory leads: after rebooting my system, its like the bios doesnt even know there is an OS installed at all. It can see the HD, but it wont boot to it. And I am unable to open GRUB in any way.

I used the Live CD to install and run boot-repair with no luck. It says it completed successfully, but does not seem to have made a difference.

Ive tried just mounting the drive so I can get the files I need and reformat the thing. But I cant seem to get that to run either. It seems to map correctly, but when trying to mount using:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/encrypted /media/encrypted
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/encrypted, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Running *dmesg | tail* from there doesnt seem to provide any actionable help.

I am getting desperate here. And any help either mounting the drive, or better-yet repairing the boot process would be eternally appreciated.

Comment: I think a default full-disk encrypted Ubuntu can use a logical volume manager - LVM scheme, so you might have to open that before mounting. *Why* they do that, instead of just having one or more regular partitions that are encrypted & mounted, I'm not sure... unless they always want to have swap on it's own virtual partition.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two stages to this.

1. decrypting
2. mounting the Logical volumes

Assuming your drive is on sda5 (which is the Ubuntu default AFAIK but might be different)

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 luks
```

You are then promted for your password.

Than do the LVM stuff

```
sudo pvscan && sudo vgscan && sudo vgchange -a y
```

Use *lsblk* if you want to find out more information about the current layout of the connected drives
after the vg are activated you can mount:

```
sudo mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /mnt
```

Now you should be able to acces the drive content. Repairing is basically a seperate question I think this might be a relevant answer [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)