# 15.04 stopped upgrading Error (1) Udev and Insserv errors

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, udev

My 15.04 will not upgrade successfully either through apt-get or otherwise. The files will download but I receive the following errors. So far I've found no solution. Udev and insserv seem to be the problem areas. Also, the machine is a server and it will not allow connections to it either through Owncloud, SSH, SFTP, or via the web address.

```
Fetched 151 MB in 15min 19s (164 kB/s)                
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (219-7ubuntu6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp_daemon.py' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and ehcp_daemon.py if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service ehcp_daemon.py at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping ehcp_daemon.py depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping ehcp depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.8-992-lowlatency
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score -1):

They just mean that the special new tags have not yet been added to the boot scripts. Try removing `insserv` and try again.

Comment: I've tried  apt-get remove insserv but I get a long list of things that will be removed with the following warnings, so I've never actually removed it out of fear of breaking it. Is it safe?
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
...
12 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 399 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,542 kB/2,363 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,758 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'

Comment: I removed insserv. At the end was this message.
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-29-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-17-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-18-generic
 systemd
 procps
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Then I ran 
sudo apt-get -f install
And got the following errors
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-29-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-17-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Also ran this and the same error code comes up.
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Nothing is solving the problem. The latest errors. dpkg: error processing package chrome-remote-desktop (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-53.2ubuntu12) ...
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp_daemon.py' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ehcp' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and ehcp_daemon.py if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service ehcp_daemon.py at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1

Comment: insserv: Stopping ehcp_daemon.py depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping ehcp depends on monit and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrome-remote-desktop
 initscripts

Comment: try an aptitude install instead of apt-get. It will show you the various options which will result in a properly working system. It might remove many packages which you can install later. I know that it is not the proper method but it is an easy work around. The bootscripts will work fine even if `insserv` is removed

Comment: I did try aptitude. No better luck. Now my system has no kernel in the GNU GRUB so I can't boot to it. I've tried booting from my Ubuntu live disks but every one from v. 10 on through 14 crashes or locks up the screen. I've tried Knoppix and Hirens rescue disks with no luck. I'm trying Super Grub 2 rescue disk next.

Comment: The kernel might have been removed when you tried aptitude or apt-get forced. You can just boot any live distro to solve it. Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels

Comment: These lines say that there is no such directory. 
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

Comment: Try creating the directory and then bind them

Comment: "chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory"

I have run which chroot and got /usr/sbin/chroot 
Advice?

Comment: Oh boy, I think I am at a loss for advices. Sorry. Let me see if I can find something.

Comment: This page has worked for the install down to SETTING UP. But I still get the error message when I try to run chroot /mnt 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

I did change the version to Vivid and use a different URL. But which chroot still returns my original chroot location. How do I tell it to look elsewhere for the chroot directory?

Comment: I renamed /usr/sbin/chroot to xchroot then installed to /usr/sbin/chroot

then I get "sudo: chroot: command not found. So I try to run "which chroot" and it gives me nothing but a return to the prompt.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Nothing worked. Reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: I am really sorry I couldn't be of help and actually caused trouble.