# Ubuntu 14.04 GNU GRUB 2.02 beta2-9 add menu entry

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Is it at all possible for me to add a menu entry in this version of GRUB2?  All solutions that I have been able to find online involve editing 40_custom, but gedit, vim, etc are all legacy GRUB commands and aren't found.

I looked through the documentation to no avail: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands

Problem:

- my Ubuntu partition isn't showing in the menu options even though I can see the partition it using `ls` in the grub shell and `ls -lh` tells me it's a filesystem
- I would really like to be able to access my Ubuntu again.

Comment: You can add entries, but if not booting then you probably have other issues. Post link that this gives: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Hi oldfred, I can't add entries right now because I can't edit 40_custom because the commands to edit aren't supported in gnu grub2.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: YES!  Visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info.  You will need an Ubuntu DVD or USB ready to boot from.  Follow its instructions, and give us the URL you will be told to give when you have finished.

Comment: Thanks for your patience guys...I misread the article initially.  Here is the pastebin URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11889706

Comment: The answer below should work, but if you run the full uninstall & reinstall of grub with Boot-Repair, it should also add the newest kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your help oldfred...I am running into a few issues with the suggested solution so I may have to give Boot-Repair a shot.  Never had a good experience working with Boot-Repair so it will be a last resort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no menu items for Ubuntu because all copies of the Linux kernel have been deleted from `/boot`. You can reinstall the kernel as follows:

Boot your computer from an Ubuntu DVD or live-USB, then choose "Try Ubuntu". Once in the Ubuntu session, connect to the internet, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and start from step 1 of the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/28100/425479.

Note that for step 2 the exact command in your case is:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

For step 5, if you have problems with internet only during this step, open a different terminal and type in it:

```
sudo cp /mnt/etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts.old
sudo cp /etc/hosts /mnt/etc/hosts
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
exit
```

then try again.

By the start of step 7, Ubuntu will have been added to the Grub menu again, ready for the reboot.

Comment: Martin, thank you for your answer with annotations.  I am stuck on stage 5 because there are missing dependencies: linux-image-3.13.0.57-generic.  Do you have any ideas?  I've read the other solutions in the post you linked, but no mention of missing dependencies.

Comment: Also, I am unable to access the internet through chroot.  Internet is working through browser...I am running Internet through a proxy if that makes a difference.

Comment: Give boot-repair a shot.  The proxy is complicating things.  The missing dependencies error was because of your internet problems, so the dependencies couldn't be installed before linux-image-generic.

Comment: Thanks Martin...I tried boot-repair soon after realizing this was most likely the case.  Boot repair was having issues that kept causing it to crash so I am now attempting to install another Ubuntu over my original partition without formatting.  Hopefully this will fix the kernel...if not I will try boot-repair again.

Comment: Installing Ubuntu via setting the old Ubuntu partition to the root directory and not formatting gave me everything on my desktop sans programs.  Proxies are still set up.  Just for future reference if anyone else does the same...