# I cannot login or open a tty

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel

Here is the situation:

I am on ubuntu 14.04 x64 with nvidia 740m graphic driver.

Last night ubuntu complained about lack of space and I tried to delete something. I followed some url and freed some space up(including deleting old linux kernels). After a reboot I couldn't login nor access tty.

I thought I accidentally delete my active kernel, so following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels) link, I booted in live cd, used chroot and installed the linux-image again. But nothing changed. It seems it cannot load any drivers, because the booting is in low graphics mode, and in the login page I can see mouse pointer but when I plug the mouse or any usb, It does nothing. (the default mouse of my laptop works, though).

What can I do now? 
My applications are very important and I don't have any time to reinstall ubuntu and reconfigure everything. So this ubuntu has to be recovered...

Comment: besides deleting some old kernels, what else have you removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was driver issue.. It couldn't load my drivers..

But it is solved with something else. As I said, I "thought" that I deleted all of the kernels.. I found one other remaining in advanced menu and it worked. I booted, removed the other kernel, install new kernel, and everything is fine now.

Something that I learned from this:

- Always, always have at least another kernel available for disaster recovery.
- Never remove a kernel with `apt-get purge --remove`, try `apt-get remove` without purge instead.