# Ran out of memory on /boot during kernel update - corrupted kernel

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I ran apt-get upgrade to update my kernel yesterday (ubuntu 15.04) and /boot ran out of memory (usually if there isn't enough space it prevents the upgrade task running)

I accidentally deleted the active kernel leading me to follow these steps here - [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

I am stuck at step 13 as the previous memory error is preventing me installing the current kernel or upgrading the remaining kernel.

Upgrade throws the following error

```
    root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -y upgrade linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... linux-image-generic is already the newest version.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (3.19.0-31.36) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Failed to symbolic-link boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic.postinst line 629.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic:
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (= 3.19.0-31.36); however:
  Package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic (= 3.19.0-31.36); however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
 linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried purging and installing fresh, no dice due to the same error

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo apt-get purge Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 3 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (3.19.0-31.36) ... Running depmod. update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later) Failed to symbolic-link boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic.postinst line 629. dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic:  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic; however:   Package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic:  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (= 3.19.0-31.36); however:   Package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic (= 3.19.0-31.36); however:   Package linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       Errors were encountered while processing:  linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic  linux-signed-image-3.19.0-31-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I believe this warrants its own question as this is a dpkg issue rather than one directly related to the question above

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what else to do, I simply removed the package

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
```

and reinstalled it

```
apt-get -y upgrade linux-image-generic
```

Seems to have done the trick