# How to regenerate grub menu entries on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty after deleting all kernels?

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I accidently removed all kernels from my Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. I followed steps in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)'s answers to install a new kernel but when I try to boot I don't see the 'Linux/ubuntu' option in my grub menu list. It only shows 'System Settings'.

How do I regenerate the earlier/default menu entries for ubuntu in grub?

Note:

1. I am currently able to boot with these steps on grub prompt:

   ```
   set root=(lvm/ubuntu--vg-root)
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
   initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
   ```

   boot
2. When on live usb, I copied `vmlinuz`, `init`... etc. from my boot partition to /boot folder because I could not find a way to use a separate boot partition from grub prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually boot with a separate /boot.

Separate /boot on sda1, / on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
insmod linux
set root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
linux (hd0,1)/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
initrd (hd0,1)/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic
boot
```

Not sure why BobaJob's instructions were down voted. If you can boot and fstab still has separate /boot that would reinstall grub to MBR. And a sudo update-grub regenerates menu.
Or use dpkg to reinstall grub.
If from live installer you can also use Boot-Repair.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Something like that should fix it, assuming your main HDD is `/dev/sda`.

If you've booted from a Live CD/USB you'll need to chroot first.
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd