# Can't remove or install kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, grub-efi

I accidentally deleted my `/boot` partition but I was able to get it back with `grub-install`

I'm trying to chroot and install the kernels again via this guide:[How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

However when I tried to remove or install the package I get the following error:

**root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install -f**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 162 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 411666 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic (4.2.0-25.30) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.2.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
mv: ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic.new’ and ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic’ are the same file
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update:** It seems to be stuck on the following command

```
root@ubuntu:/# update-initramfs -c -t -k 4.2.0-25-generic -b /boot
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
mv: ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic.new’ and ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic’ are the same file
```

**root@ubuntu:/# ls -l /boot**

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -l /boot

```
total 5430
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1268815 Apr 17  2015 abi-3.19.0-15-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177656 Apr 17  2015 config-3.19.0-15-generic
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      60 Jan 20 21:39 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  164216 Mar  6  2015 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  165892 Mar  6  2015 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166396 Mar  6  2015 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 3615358 Apr 17  2015 System.map-3.19.0-15-generic
```

**root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic:amd64
```

**root@ubuntu:/# dpkg --configure linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic**

```
Setting up linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (4.2.0-25.30) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic
mv: ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic.new’ and ‘/boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-25-generic’ are the same file
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Before you chroot do a `mount /dev /chrooted/system/dev -o bind` and then `mount /dev/pts /chrooted/system/dev/pts -o bind` where `/chrooted/system` is a directory you mounted your old system.

Comment: I'm doing this from a live disk, /dev/pts seems to be empty

Comment: You mean /dev/pts on your live system?

Comment: @nsilent22 Yeah, I meant to say I'm using an Ubuntu Live CD and there's nothing in `/dev/pts`. So when I mount it in `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/root/` along with all the other mounts `/dev/pts/` seems to be empty and I still get the same error above.

Comment: Ok, I understand /home/ubuntu/Desktop/root is a directory where you mount your 'old' filesystem. Then try mounting devpts explicitly: `mount devpts /home/ubuntu/Desktop/root/dev/pts -t devpts`

Comment: @nsilent22 ok the devpts error went away but the rest of the error is still there

Comment: When pasting the output of a command, also give the command itself. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem sure, pasted the command the kernel install is getting stuck at

Comment: I meant the actual command you are running which produces the output you pasted. ;) While you are at it, what is the output of `ls -l /boot`?

Comment: @fkraiem There's everything as you requested.

Comment: The question you have linked does not apply to you: in that question, the OP had removed his kernel packages using `apt-get remove`, but you have just deleted the files. What you should do is `apt-get install --reinstall` on GRUB and all your kernel packages.

Comment: @fkraiem I've tried those commands, please take a look at the output errors I get when running that.

Comment: This looks very bad... From what I gather, you get the "Internal Error" because you are trying to reinstall a package which is not fully configured, but you cannot configure it due to the missing files. I assume reinstalling the system is not an option?

Comment: @fkraiem Yes, you're right. But, phew! Somehow I think I figured it out.  Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a hint above at not being able to process  something about `postinst.d` so I looked at what scripts it was running and found them.

I did a `rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic.*` which had some `.postrm` and `.list` files that were being used and those were faulty for whatever reason. I removed them, ran `dpkg --configure -a` and no more reinstall errors! Yay. Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction. There was another hint about reinstalling grub which I did with Boot Repair and after that I was able to pinpoint better where things were broken.

Comment: When I do a `uname -r` I get `4.2.0-25-generic
`. But when I do `dpkg --configure linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
` I get `dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 no package named 'linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic' is installed, cannot configure
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic
`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @kwoxer did you run `uname -r` to see what kernel version you have?

Comment: I was already able to solve it. Thanks anyway: http://serverfault.com/questions/780980/error-could-not-open-directory-lib-modules-4-2-0-25-generic-no-such-file-or-d/782884