# After going through an Ubuntu software update, system fails to boot

Tags: grub2, kernel, reboot, boot-repair

It goes like this:

Ubutu 14.04 LTS

I keep it fairly up to date.  Usually allow updates when nagged.
Was nagged this morning and allowed update.  Rebooted.  Got a message that something failed.  Assumed it was because my /boot was full (again!).  Used a procedure that I have used many times to purge old kernel and related files to reclaim space.  Assume I over-reclaimed".  Ran updater again.  It then said I had to reboot.  Allowed reboot.  Nothing there but air.

I am now running from the original install CD (try ubuntu option).  Installed boot-repair but it is **stuck** on *"Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel sda6 (ins).  This may require severlal minutes"*

Then I installed boot-info and created a report here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15206613/

Any advice?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Same here. Fresh install from ISO, made a clone, updated the clone. Update hangs "configuring grub-pc".

Answer (score 0):

OK. Its fixed now by boot-repair.  Not sure what I did to fix it but I killed the one that was hung and tried this:

[How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels#)

Rebooted.  No help.

Then I tried reinstalling grub (sorry, lost the link but it was a vanilla sudo apt-get ... command).

Rebooted.  No help.

After those two attempts, I rebooted from the 14.04 install CD (try ubuntu option), then ran boot-repair again and it completed with a happy message saying that it was fixed and I could reboot.  Maybe it would have just worked the second time through without my other gyrations.

Rebooted.  Profit!

Good luck to those who come along later on.