# How to recover boot ubuntu 14.04 on macbook-pro?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, macbook-pro

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on a macbook pro. I was trying to make a usb stick for a customize boot from terminal when i stop the process. I lost the boot. I cant boot anymore. I enter in the grub menu, but if I choose normal boot, it stuck. If I choose the repair, it stops on the repair menu and write " disabling irq #17" . I have tried to reinstall system following [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels).

But it is not booting yet. Any suggestions? I can boot using the usb stick and I can see my hd (/dev/sda4).

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a live CD then use it to install again.
>
> But If you dont have one follow this
>
> 1. Find out which devices are available:
>
>    ls
> 2. Set to the correct value, which might be something like this:
>
> `set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub`
>
> (this has to be done according to your own drive name)
>
> ```
> set root=(hd0,1)
> ```
>
> (this has to be performed according to your own drive name.)
>
> ```
> insmod normal 
> normal
> ```
>
> The above commands will get you out of the rescue mode to the normal
>   terminal mode. In the terminal mode you have more commands with
>   increased functionality. After the above commands you can go ahead and
>   start the rest of the settings.
>
> ```
> insmod linux
> * linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro
> ```
>
> (if this doesn't work try this)
>
> ```
> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-14-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro
> ```
>
> (optional)
>
> ```
> initrd /initrd.img
> ```
>
> (Selects the initrd image.)
>
> ```
> boot
> ```
>
> After Booting the system. Update the GRUB config file.
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Reinstallation of Grub on the device:
>
> ```
> sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
> ```

Hope I helped, Original [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! When formatting your answers, please us {} to format the code and "" to quote anything from an external source. You can click `edit` below your post to see the formatting, thanks.