# GNU GRUB Ubuntu option gone!

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

Hi there I seem to have a serious problem that google wasn't able to help me with. I'm a novice with GNU systems. I was clearing up some space on my boot folder (which of course what I think went wrong) because the memory was full for more updates. I followed some instructions I found on the web and everything was working fine. I have another hard-disk with Win10 that I use to game on. After the reset, I tried to return to Ubuntu when I came to the GNU GRUB menu as always and behold there is no more Ubuntu option.

This stinks. What should I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)

Answer (score 0):

`/boot` contains bootloader, kernel and other images, what will boot. If you deleted some files, you can fall in to `grub rescue`, or something like that. If you will not get Grub at all, get a Live Image, and follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If you must free up some space, you should use package manager (apt-get) to [remove old kernels SAFELY](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-delete-old-kernel-images-command/).

Comment: I tried the boot-repair from live CD and it hasn't fixed my problem. I cleaned out old kernals, linux images, and so on. Now since it is encrypted, I've run into a whole other mess.

Comment: No, it is not a problem, that you've encrypted your files, but the problem is, that you deleted kernels, and boot images. You can restore them, by booting to a Live Disk & reinstalling grub to the MBR: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd - However, if it will not able to find the remaining kernels  then install it via `apt-get install linux-image-generic` in chroot (http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels). If you can't, then comment, and I'll help.