# linux-image/headers-extra-3.19.0-25-generic(3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1)

Tags: 14.04

I accidentally removed these four items when i was trying to remove katoolin:

[image]

I just need to know if they're critical to the OS in any way.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please [edit] your question and describe what you have done and what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Those items are **kernel files**. They are the files that your Ubuntu installation requires when it boots up.

Unless if you have other kernels (linux-{image|headers}-XXXX} installed (which doesn't look like it), you're good to go. Otherwise, your system might not boot up.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels) might be a solution.