# Any flavor of Debian or UBUNTU still being made in amd64+mac version?

Tags: uefi

I have a Lenovo Z475 which does not support UEFI booting. So it freezes on grub. All the AMD64+MAC editions are all OLD distros. Is there any distro still being made and supported in AMD64+MAC?

Comment: 14.04 is still supported: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/

Comment: Anything up-to-date? or recent or when 14.04 dies out, I'm stuck?

Comment: Considering there's another 3 years left for 14.04 to die out, maybe you should think of getting new hardware three years later.

Comment: Current (16.04) versions still support BIOS-mode booting, so your deduction that the problem is due to your computer not supporting EFI-mode booting is incorrect. More likely, you used a tool that failed to set up the BIOS-mode boot loader correctly. Try another tool (`dd`, UNetbootin, Rufus, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with every imaging tool you could image. I though it was that as well at first.  Including DD and UNETBOOTIN. I pickup an old copy of the AMD64+MAC version and that solved my problem. Grub no longer froze when I booted from a LIVE USB.

Comment: https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 14.04 amd64+mac LIVE USB to install Xenial.

Install the base 14.04 and don't do the updates, they will be wasted time and bandwidth.

Replace the /etc/apt/sources.lst with Xenials version generated from https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Then CTRL-ALT-F1 to a terminal. Login. Run 'sudo -i'. Enter your password.

Run 'apt-get update' then 'apt-get dist-upgrade'

Finish with an 'apt-get autoremove' then 'reboot'

Do not install AMD64-MICROCODE yet as it has problems as of this post.

Enjoy Xenial! Keep your 14.04 AMD64+MAC image in a safe place as this is your gateway to installing new distros. This is not an official fix, it's just a workaround that worked for me. Your mileage may vary.

**If you installed AMD64-MICROCODE by mistake(after rebooting into Xenial your driver manager app will suggest it) and can't boot your laptop anymore. Do not worry, you won't have to reinstall everything all over again. Boot from your 14.04 AMD64+MAC live USB and follow these instructions on this answer: [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)
Except you will also add 'sudo mount --bind /boot /mnt/boot' to the list of special partitions to mount. The command you will run is 'sudo apt-get remove --purge amd64-microcode' then follow the rest of the answer to exit, unmount, and reboot.

*** You can also just do numerous 'do-release-upgrade' until you get to 16.04.  That worked for me as well.