# How to restore kernel in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel

I accidentally removed the kernel from my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS while trying to update it. Now when I start it up, my Grub2 doesn't show Ubuntu as an option anymore. So I boot up the Live USB drive and try Ubuntu, and ran GParted to check out which partition the Ubuntu was installed in. I'm lost. Can someone help me recover the kernel?

Just in case, I am dual-booting Ubuntu alongside with Windows 10. Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please upload a better screenshot ? with all columns visible ? I am not seeing any Ubuntu partitions. (If those 3 ntfs are on windows)

Comment: @SeverusTux /dev/sda5 is Ubuntu. It's right there.

Comment: Please use this link ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels/166010#166010

Comment: Following wjandrea's guide worked. The trick was to know which partition it is. In my case, it was sda5 (replace sdXY with sda5 on step #2). Sorry for the duplicate thread.