# Restore linux kernel after accidental removal

Tags: boot, partitioning, kernel, mount

I accidentally removed my current linux kernel from my **Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS** by using this command: `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-{77,79}-generic`

Unable to boot into the system, now I found this good [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/166010) on how to re-install kernel.

But, problem is `sudo parted -l` is showing `boot` flag is set for `sda1` but `ext4` partition is in disk `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` as opposed to usual `sdaX`. [Output of `sudo parted -l`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17363218/).

Now, I'm unable to decide which filesystem to mount for re-installing kernel:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Or

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/boot
```

Here is [Pastebin of Boot-Repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17160435/)

Comment: Do you have any kernels installed at all?

Comment: @eyoung100: No, I accidentally removed all kernels including current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess, you have a separate partition for `/boot`. That's not unusual, the installer does that when using LVM.

First mount `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` at `/mnt`, and then mount `/dev/sda2` at `/mnt/boot`.

Comment: I'm still confused for `/dev/sda2`. Why it is not `/dev/sda1` when `boot` flag is set for it? Also, should it be `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` OR `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root1`

Comment: `/boot` contains files for the GRUB bootloader to use after it has started booting. It doesn't have to be flagged `boot`. And I don't see a `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root1` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore my linux kernel using commands provided in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/166010/273086). Special thanks to @muru for extending help.

For reference, here are commands I executed:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls /mnt/boot
efi
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt

root@ubuntu:/# mount -t proc none /proc
root@ubuntu:/# mount -t sysfs none /sys
root@ubuntu:/# mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
root@ubuntu:/# export HOME=/root
root@ubuntu:/# export LC_ALL=C

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get update
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -y install linux-image-generic

root@ubuntu:/# umount /proc || umount -lf /proc
root@ubuntu:/# umount /sys /dev/pts
root@ubuntu:/# exit
exit
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /mnt/dev /mnt
```