# Boots into Blinking Cursor and Black Screen After Auto Update

Tags: boot, updates

14.04 LTS.
Auto updated, rebooted, bios posts, goes to a black screen with blinking cursor.
Holding shift after Bios post will display the letters GRUB but nothing else.
No other inputs appear to have any effect (tried "alt ->" and "alt<-"; also tried alt+ctrl+f1; and typing my password + enter)
I can still dual boot into Windows.
I can boot into a Live CD but unsure how to fix this.
Last month I had this problem:
[After Repairing Deleted Kernel, why would GRUB still not boot into Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915617/after-repairing-deleted-kernel-why-would-grub-still-not-boot-into-linux/918708#918708).
I just tried those steps again, shooting in the dark, to no avail.
Please help...  What is going on with my Ubuntu install!?

Comment: A good start would be to start ubuntu via additional choises of grub with the previous kernel... This will do clear if the new kernel causes your problem

Comment: Also are the updates that you did ordinary updates? or you upgraded to 16.04?

Comment: But how do I start Ubuntu with GRUB when GRUB never appears? Also, I ran auto updates and auto installed whatever it gave me (a long list,  and it took a lot longer than usual)

Comment: did you tell it to remove the current kernel while you were updating?

Comment: @MOwens sorry, I thought you could boot. Offtopic:(when we say I can dual boot we mean I can boot in both. Otherwise it is better to say I can boot on Windows)

Comment: Sorry koleygr I understand that was confusing. @ravery I didn't remove any kernels, or anything at all from the boot partition

Answer (score 1):

if you get grub. from a LiveCD. press c to get a command line.
change the drive refences as need for your install

From grub type `ls (hd0,2)/boot/`

you should see a file named vmlinuz or linux, and initrd.img. with version numbers

type: `linux (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-#### root=/dev/sda2` or `linux (hd0,2)/boot/linux-#### root=/dev/sda2` depending on what you found with ls (hd0,1)/ then

```
`initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initrd-#####.img`
```

`boot`

if you get initramfs rescue mode -- enter your password then startx
you should now have a desktop.

use gparted to check your file system, if it reports an error, then you need to boot from a LiveCD or other media to fix it .... DO NOT attempt to repair a mounted partition.

The following three commands fix many grub boot problems. They run quick so just do all three instead of trying to find which one you need.

`sudo install-grub /dev/sda`, `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`

reboot and see what you get