# Can't boot my MacBook Air 2017 after sudo pm-hibernate

Tags: macbook, hibernate

Looks like hardware simply does not support such a command. Whenever I try start Ubuntu (> 16), it tries to boot and in 2 secs screen became totally black. Nothing helps.

Just don't tell me I need to reinstall it.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steve said in the comment, there has been a problem with hibernation in some of the kernels shipped with ubuntu, which is described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743094

From my limited reading, it seems to have started at 4.13.0-25, and still be a problem in 4.13.0-32

After I encountered this, I could still get into GRUB. I used `Advanced options for Ubuntu > Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-53 (recovery mode)`, and ran `swapoff --all` in a root-shell, ran `fsck`, and updated grub. After doing this, I was able to boot into my system again :) -- all steps might not have been necessary though.

Comment: Ah, I am not that smart to recover things from the GRUB. Just reinstalled whole system and it goes fine since that time.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have an old kernel that you can use to boot the system, install an older kernel using live cd as described in [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels)