# Packages broken & apt does not work after aborted Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04 LTS (from 14)

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I attempted to upgrade Ubuntu 14 to 16 LTS using `sudo do-release-upgrade` and everything is broken. The installation is not completed. The logs say it was aborted. When I use `apt` or `apt-get` the following output is shown (see below). It seems installation of some packages have left incomplete. All attempts failed.

I managed to `chroot` into an Ubuntu 16 from CDROM (in fact from HDD) and fixed a few things. But I cannot install the new kernel.  (from [How to restore a system after accidentally removing all kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels))

Various things I tried:

- sudo dpkg --configure t
- apt-get -f install
- dpkg -l | grep -v '^ii'|cut -c5-64 >list-of-packages.txt
- dpkg --configure $(

  sudo dpkg --configure -a

  Replaced sources.list with the original file.

  sudo apt-get install --fix-broken

  sudo do-release-upgrade  # No new release found.

  ...

Output of `uname -a`

> Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18
>   08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output of: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

> arangodb.list            github_git-lfs.list.save
>   nodesource.list.distUpgrade
>   staticfloat-juliareleases-trusty.list.distUpgrade
>   arangodb.list.distUpgrade    google-chrome.list
>   nodesource.list.save                staticfloat-juliareleases-trusty.list.save
>   arangodb.list.save           google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
>   paolorotolo-droidcam-trusty.list        tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list
>   d-apt.list               google-chrome.list.save
>   paolorotolo-droidcam-trusty.list.distUpgrade
>   tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list.distUpgrade d-apt.list.distUpgrade
>   google-cloud-sdk.list       paolorotolo-droidcam-trusty.list.save
>   tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list.save d-apt.list.save
>   google-cloud-sdk.list.distUpgrade   rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server.list
>   ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list docker.list
>   google-cloud-sdk.list.save
>   rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server.list.distUpgrade
>   ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list.distUpgrade
>   docker.list.distUpgrade          linrunner-tlp-trusty.list          sbt.list
>   ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list.save docker.list.save
>   linrunner-tlp-trusty.list.distUpgrade  sbt.list.distUpgrade
>   webupd8team-java-trusty.list erlang-solutions.list
>   linrunner-tlp-trusty.list.save      sbt.list.save
>   webupd8team-java-trusty.list.distUpgrade
>   erlang-solutions.list.distUpgrade  neo4j.list
>   staticfloat-julia-deps-trusty.list
>   webupd8team-java-trusty.list.save erlang-solutions.list.save
>   neo4j.list.distUpgrade
>   staticfloat-julia-deps-trusty.list.distUpgrade 
>   webupd8team-unstable-trusty.list github_git-lfs.list
>   neo4j.list.save             staticfloat-julia-deps-trusty.list.save
>   webupd8team-unstable-trusty.list.distUpgrade
>   github_git-lfs.list.distUpgrade    nodesource.list
>   staticfloat-juliareleases-trusty.list
>   webupd8team-unstable-trusty.list.save

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
Output along list including the following lines:

> ...
>   dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--configure): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of libkwalletbackend5-5:amd64: 
>   libkwalletbackend5-5:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
>   Package libstdc++6:amd64 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package libkwalletbackend5-5:amd64
>   (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
>   dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64:  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64
>   depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1); however:   Package libstdc++6:amd64
>   is not configured yet. ... Processing was halted because there were
>   too many errors.

The output I get when I do any apt-like command (e.g. `sudo apt install linux-image-generic` ) is the following:

> ## sudo apt install linux-image-generic Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You
>
> might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The following
>   packages have unmet dependencies:  click : Depends: python3-click (=
>   0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2) but 6.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed  empathy : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not installable
>              Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not installable
>              Recommends: telepathy-haze but it is not going to be installed
>              Recommends: gnome-contacts but it is not going to be installed
>              Recommends: nautilus-sendto-empathy but it is not installable  gstreamer1.0-clutter : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but
>   it is not installable  libbaloofiles4 : Depends: libxapian22 but it is
>   not installable  libbalooxapian4 : Depends: libxapian22 but it is not
>   installable  libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to
>   be installed  libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.0.1-0ubuntu1) but it
>   is not going to be installed  libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-6-base (=
>   6.4.0-17ubuntu1~14.04) but it is not going to be installed  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.4) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                           Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libicu55:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>=
>   1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>=
>   1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libllvm3.8v4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386
>   (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not going to be installed  libllvm6.0:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>=
>   1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libmysqlclient18:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386
>   (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed 
>   libmysqlclient20:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libqapt2-runtime : Depends: libqapt2 (>=
>   1.9.60) but it is not installable  libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is
>   not going to be installed
>                              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-designer : Depends: libqt4-xml (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                      Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed  libqt4-dev
>   : Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                 Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                 Depends: qt4-qmake (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2)  libqt4-dev-bin : Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                     Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-help : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                          Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2)
>   but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                         Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqt4-xml (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                        Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not
>   going to be installed
>                         Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                         Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-scripttools : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.0)
>   but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386
>   (>= 1:3.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                            Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                            Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-sql-sqlite : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-svg : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-test : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1)
>   but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqt4-xmlpatterns : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>=
>   1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed
>                              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqtcore4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386
>   (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed  libqtdbus4 : Depends: libqt4-xml (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>                 Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   libqtdbus4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:3.0) but it is not going
>   to be installed
>                      Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                      Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                      Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed  libqtgui4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed  libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but
>   it is not going to be installed
>                     Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                     Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
>                     Recommends: qt-at-spi:i386 but it is not going to be installed  libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but
>   it is not going to be installed
>                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed  libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-3)
>   but 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
>                 Breaks: libboost-date-time1.54.0 but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
>                 Breaks: python-scipy (<= 0.14.1-1) but 0.13.3-1build1 is to be installed  libsystemd0:i386 : PreDepends: libgcc1:i386 (>=
>   1:4.2) but it is not going to be installed  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 :
>   Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be
>   installed  libubuntu-location-service0 : Depends: libgflags2 but it is
>   not installable
>                                  Depends: libgoogle-glog0 but it is not installable  libudev1:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it
>   is not going to be installed  qdbus : Depends: libqt4-xml (=
>   4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is
>   to be installed
>            Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   qt4-linguist-tools : Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but
>   4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
>                         Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed 
>   ubuntu-system-settings : Depends:
>   qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components (> 0.7+15.04.20160310) but
>   0.1+14.04.20140306-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
>                             Depends: suru-icon-theme (>= 14.04+15.04.20150813~) but 14.04+14.04.20140410-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
>                             Depends: system-image-dbus (>= 3.1) but 2.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
>                             Depends: ubuntu-keyboard-data (>= 0.99.trunk.phablet2+15.04.20150421) but 0.99.trunk.phablet2+14.04.20140415-0ubuntu1 is to be installed  xchat-gnome : Depends: libperl5.18 (>= 5.18.2) but it is not
>   installable  zeitgeist-core : Depends: libxapian22 but it is not
>   installable E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
>   packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I replaced the contents of sources.list with tje contents at this address: https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1  But I dont know how to check the ppa of libcheese-gtk*

Comment: Best practice before a release-upgrade is to uninstall all PPA and other non-Ubuntu software to prevent precisely this kind of situation. Next time, try to return your Ubuntu system to as close to stock condition as possible before starting the release-upgrade. Advice: Backup your data and do a clean install - recovering from a botched release-upgrade is generally not worthwhile.

Comment: Reflecting back, this might have been a consequence of a defective hard drive (bad sectors) which was occurring at the time.

Answer (score 2):

The repository may have been corrupted. You can use the following command to clean out your apt list:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then update with

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all files into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for duplicates or invalid packages

`apt-get clean`

and then

`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`