# Accidently deleted all kernels. How to put a kernal back so can boot again with old data?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kernel

So I had memory full and couldn't boot(biggest culprit was docker volumes). during the cleanup I accidentally deleted all kernels hence nothing in the boot loader. I installed a new 18.04 in /dev/sda3. But i dont want to copy all the data over to this and install everything again.

Ideally what I want is, if possible,

1. Somehow install new kernel to the old /dev/sda2 the /boot/ is kinda
   empty now and /boot/efi is totally empty.
2. Delete the newly installed OS and free the all the space and add into the old partition.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/28099/how-to-restore-a-system-after-accidentally-removing-all-kernels Old but still rlelevant

Comment: this inst working entirely as I already have another OS now and the mount from shell will mount the current / dir. I dont know who to point to the old one

Comment: " I dont know who to point to the old one" it is in the link how to do that. And you said /dev/sda2. So apply your dev to the instructions in the link