# Changing Languages on Login / BIOS Screen

Tags: keyboard, login, startup, bios, language-support

I recently installed Lubuntu on one of my old PCs, and put in a password in English.
The next time I opened my computer and was asked for my password only the Hebrew keyboard was available, leaving me unable to log in.

Eventually I learnt that you can change your administrator password through the BIOS menu, unfortunately it appears that menu is also stuck on Hebrew, leaving it in a nonfunctional state.

Does anybody know how I could revert my typing language back to English, either in the login screen, or in the BIOS menu?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

- Login with LiveCD (Try Ubuntu without Installing)
- Mount your root partition in read/write mode: `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdXY /mnt -o rw`
- Edit your `/mnt/etc/default/keyboard` file. Mine is:

  ```
    $ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
    XKBLAYOUT="us,ua,ru"
    XKBVARIANT=",winkeys,"
    BACKSPACE="guess"
    XKBMODEL="pc105"
    XKBOPTIONS="grp:toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
  ```

And you could also change your `/mnt/etc/default/locale` to:

```
    $ cat /etc/default/locale 
    #  File generated by update-locale
    LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=en_GB
```

I generated it by

```
sudo update-locale LANGUAGE=en_GB
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
. /etc/default/locale
```

If that will not help, then you could try [chrooting](https://askubuntu.com/a/28100/925971) your system and execute

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: Thank you, sadly I couldn't manage to reach the LiveCD login (Probably something to do with my very old computer), so I reinstalled Lubunto. Nonetheless I'm sure this explanation will help people with similar problems :)

Comment: The right path is `/mnt/etc/default/keyboard` and not `/mnt/etc/defaults/keyboard`