# PC won't boot after changing Nvidia additional drivers

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia

I have a Dell G3 15 3500 with a Nvidia 1650 Ti running Ubuntu 23.04. I changed additional drivers to one of the latest proprietary drivers wich I think it is: “Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia 525 (proprietary).

After, it prompted a restart. I restarted, but now the laptop won’t iniciate (STUCK in the loading page, with the saying: Dell| Ubuntu). I’m stuck on a black screen with GNU GRUB version 2.06. I was able to go to the “One time booting settings” as well. Nothing further.

I need to go back to the other Nvidia additional driver but I don't know how.

[image: photo of a laptop screen; black screen with white text that is blurry and not legible or barely legible]

Comment: Nope ;/ i will send a pic

Comment: First try and get into console mode, so that you can run commands from Recovery mode.

Comment: It doesnt seems to work beacause everything I type in this black screen GNU GRUB VERSION 2.06 wont work. It says “error: cant find command ‘sudo…’

Comment: I cant :((((  i tried crtl + alt + f3. I tried shit + power buton. Esc ++ power button. Always go to the page in the image. :/

Comment: You don't need to access recovery mode. You can boot the Ubuntu installation USB to an Ubuntu live session and [chroot](https://askubuntu.com/q/28099/) into your Ubuntu installation from there.

Comment: You need to [boot to a root shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558). On another note, I've cleaned up your question. If you still are having problems, please take good notes. When all of your details are annotated with comments like *"I think"* or *"something like"*, it doesn't give us much confidence that we are working with accurate information. If you're not sure about something, look it up. Double check your question for accuracy before and after posting. Edit if necessary. Let's avoid trying fix the wrong thing based on a typo, mistake, lack of due diligence, or other miscommunication.

Comment: I dont have a CD and i cant open the terminal. I can only program through the GRUB.

Comment: I tried as well the safe boot option. Nothing works.

Comment: Help please!! What do I do from the “grub>”??? What commands should I use?